# Python: split on two different expressions?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python strings split with multiple separators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059559/python-strings-split-with-multiple-separators)

Is there a way in Python to split a string on two different keys?

Say I have a string like this:

```
mystr = "wketjwlektjwltjkw<br/>wwwweltjwetlkwjww" + \
         "wwetlwjtwlet<strong>wwwwketjwlektjwlk</strong"
```

I'd like to split on EITHER `<br/>wwww` or `<strong>wwww`.

How should I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python strings split with multiple separators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059559/python-strings-split-with-multiple-separators). Short answer: use a regular expression.

Comment: Oh yes, it is a duplicate, sorry about that!

Comment: Do you want that if both the characters exist the string gets divided into 3 lists ??? mystr.split('<br/>' or '<strong>wwww>') works if you want that whichever exists first gets split into 2 lists....

Comment: No! That will evaluate `'<br/>' or '<strong>wwww>'` first, resulting in `'<br/>'`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
import re
re.split(r'<(br\/|strong)>wwww', mystr)[::2]
```

Comment: re.split() includes the separators in the output, using `[::2]` might be of interest to skip those.

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't come up with an immediate solution to that, but yours is nice. I'll add it.