# Get rid of stopwords and punctuation

Tags: python, nltk, stop-words

I'm struggling with NLTK stopword.

Here's my bit of code.. Could someone tell me what's wrong?

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

def removeStopwords( palabras ):
     return [ word for word in palabras if word not in stopwords.words('spanish') ]

palabras = ''' my text is here '''
```

Comment: Are you just missing the call to the function? Try adding `print removeStopwords(palabras)` after your last line.

Comment: Right!!! I've missed it!

Comment: I don't know if you faced the problem that stopwords.words('spanish') return a list where not every word is encoded with Unicode.
So, checking whether a word is present in words encoded with Unicode (u'word'), and using 'in' operator, can lead to a wrong comparison. 

I got this message: 
UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal

any clue? I guess NLTK.CORPUS.STOPWORDS should return unicoded lists
gracias!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Your problem is that the iterator for a string returns each character not each word.

For example:

```
>>> palabras = "Buenos dias"
>>> [c for c in palabras]
['B', 'u', 'e', 'n', 'a', 's', ' ', 'd', 'i', 'a', 's']
```

You need to iterate and check each word, fortunately the split function already exists in the python standard library under the [string module](http://docs.python.org/release/2.3/lib/module-string.html). However you are dealing with natural language including punctuation you should look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059559/python-strings-split-with-multiple-separators) for a more robust answer that uses the `re` module.

Once you have a list of words you should lowercase them all before comparison and then compare them in the manner that you have shown already.

Buena suerte.

### EDIT 1

Okay try this code, it should work for you. It shows two ways to do it, they are essentially identical but the first is a bit clearer while the second is more pythonic.

```
import re
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

scentence = 'El problema del matrimonio es que se acaba todas las noches despues de hacer el amor, y hay que volver a reconstruirlo todas las mananas antes del desayuno.'

#We only want to work with lowercase for the comparisons
scentence = scentence.lower() 

#remove punctuation and split into seperate words
words = re.findall(r'\w+', scentence,flags = re.UNICODE | re.LOCALE) 

#This is the simple way to remove stop words
important_words=[]
for word in words:
    if word not in stopwords.words('spanish'):
        important_words.append(word)

print important_words

#This is the more pythonic way
important_words = filter(lambda x: x not in stopwords.words('spanish'), words)

print important_words
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: We use "Buena suerte". the re module help me with the punctuation, but i'm still trying to combine it with the stopword function

Comment: Turn the stopwords into a set, it will be **a lot** faster.

Comment: If they are using nltk already why just not use a Tokenizer and solve it in three lines?

Answer (score 4):

Using a tokenizer first you compare a list of tokens (symbols) against the stoplist, so you don't need the re module. I added an extra argument in order to switch among languages.

```
def remove_stopwords(sentence, language):
    return [ token for token in nltk.word_tokenize(sentence) if token.lower() not in stopwords.words(language) ]
```

Dime si te fue de util ;)

Answer (score 2):

Another option with more modern modules (2020)

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from textblob import TextBlob

def removeStopwords( texto):
    blob = TextBlob(texto).words
    outputlist = [word for word in blob if word not in stopwords.words('spanish')]
    return(' '.join(word for word in outputlist))
```