# NLTK: corpus-level bleu vs sentence-level BLEU score

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, nltk, bleu

I have imported nltk in python to calculate BLEU Score on Ubuntu. I understand how sentence-level BLEU score works, but I don't understand how corpus-level BLEU score work.

Below is my code for corpus-level BLEU score:

```
import nltk

hypothesis = ['This', 'is', 'cat'] 
reference = ['This', 'is', 'a', 'cat']
BLEUscore = nltk.translate.bleu_score.corpus_bleu([reference], [hypothesis], weights = [1])
print(BLEUscore)
```

For some reason, the bleu score is 0 for the above code. I was expecting a corpus-level BLEU score of at least 0.5.

Here is my code for sentence-level BLEU score

```
import nltk

hypothesis = ['This', 'is', 'cat'] 
reference = ['This', 'is', 'a', 'cat']
BLEUscore = nltk.translate.bleu_score.sentence_bleu([reference], hypothesis, weights = [1])
print(BLEUscore)
```

Here the sentence-level BLEU score is 0.71 which I expect, taking into account the brevity-penalty and the missing word "a". However, I don't understand how corpus-level BLEU score work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hopefully the documentation and the doctest / unittest in the code helps you. But please pull the latest version of `nltk` in order to have a stabilized version of BLEU. Actually, how you're using the function is not really correct, will explain in an answer =)

Comment: from wikipedia, might be of interest to this line of questioning. `BLEU is designed to approximate human judgement at a corpus level, and performs badly if used to evaluate the quality of individual sentences.` Maybe the line of questioning is not relevant to the metric.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

**TL;DR**:

```
>>> import nltk
>>> hypothesis = ['This', 'is', 'cat'] 
>>> reference = ['This', 'is', 'a', 'cat']
>>> references = [reference] # list of references for 1 sentence.
>>> list_of_references = [references] # list of references for all sentences in corpus.
>>> list_of_hypotheses = [hypothesis] # list of hypotheses that corresponds to list of references.
>>> nltk.translate.bleu_score.corpus_bleu(list_of_references, list_of_hypotheses)
0.6025286104785453
>>> nltk.translate.bleu_score.sentence_bleu(references, hypothesis)
0.6025286104785453
```

(Note: You have to pull the latest version of NLTK on the `develop` branch in order to get a stable version of the BLEU score implementation)

---

**In Long**:

Actually, if there's only one reference and one hypothesis in your whole corpus, both `corpus_bleu()` and `sentence_bleu()` should return the same value as shown in the example above.

In the code, we see that [`sentence_bleu` is actually a duck-type of `corpus_bleu`](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/translate/bleu_score.py#L26):

```
def sentence_bleu(references, hypothesis, weights=(0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25),
                  smoothing_function=None):
    return corpus_bleu([references], [hypothesis], weights, smoothing_function)
```

And if we look at the parameters for `sentence_bleu`:

```
 def sentence_bleu(references, hypothesis, weights=(0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25),
                      smoothing_function=None):
    """"
    :param references: reference sentences
    :type references: list(list(str))
    :param hypothesis: a hypothesis sentence
    :type hypothesis: list(str)
    :param weights: weights for unigrams, bigrams, trigrams and so on
    :type weights: list(float)
    :return: The sentence-level BLEU score.
    :rtype: float
    """
```

The input for `sentence_bleu`'s references is a `list(list(str))`.

So if you have a sentence string, e.g. `"This is a cat"`, you have to tokenized it to get a list of strings, `["This", "is", "a", "cat"]` and since it allows for multiple references, it has to be a list of list of string, e.g. if you have a second reference, "This is a feline", your input to `sentence_bleu()` would be:

```
references = [ ["This", "is", "a", "cat"], ["This", "is", "a", "feline"] ]
hypothesis = ["This", "is", "cat"]
sentence_bleu(references, hypothesis)
```

When it comes to `corpus_bleu()` list_of_references parameter, it's basically [a list of whatever the `sentence_bleu()` takes as references](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/translate/bleu_score.py#L82):

```
def corpus_bleu(list_of_references, hypotheses, weights=(0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25),
                smoothing_function=None):
    """
    :param references: a corpus of lists of reference sentences, w.r.t. hypotheses
    :type references: list(list(list(str)))
    :param hypotheses: a list of hypothesis sentences
    :type hypotheses: list(list(str))
    :param weights: weights for unigrams, bigrams, trigrams and so on
    :type weights: list(float)
    :return: The corpus-level BLEU score.
    :rtype: float
    """
```

Other than look at the doctest within the [`nltk/translate/bleu_score.py`](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/translate/bleu_score.py), you can also take a look at the unittest at [`nltk/test/unit/translate/test_bleu_score.py`](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/test/unit/translate/test_bleu.py) to see how to use each of the component within the `bleu_score.py`.

By the way, since the `sentence_bleu` is imported as `bleu` in the (`nltk.translate.__init__.py`]([https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/translate/**init**.py#L21](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/translate/__init__.py#L21)), using

```
from nltk.translate import bleu
```

would be the same as:

```
from nltk.translate.bleu_score import sentence_bleu
```

and in code:

```
>>> from nltk.translate import bleu
>>> from nltk.translate.bleu_score import sentence_bleu
>>> from nltk.translate.bleu_score import corpus_bleu
>>> bleu == sentence_bleu
True
>>> bleu == corpus_bleu
False
```

Comment: How about upper letters and low letters

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541745/get-rid-of-stopwords-and-punctuation

Comment: Try it for yourself ;P Also, note BLEU was never meant to do sentence level computation. It's a corpus level metric.

Comment: @alvas how did you get the BLEU score of 0.6025286104785453 in your first example? It seems to be 0 when using NLTK '3.4.5' version, without the smoothing function.

Comment: `import nltk
hypothesis = ['This', 'is', 'cat'] 
reference = ['This', 'is', 'a', 'cat']
references = [reference] # list of references for 1 sentence.
list_of_references = [references] # list of references for all sentences in corpus.
list_of_hypotheses = [hypothesis] # list of hypotheses that corresponds to list of references.


nltk.translate.bleu_score.sentence_bleu(references, hypothesis)`  `8.987727354491445e-155`

Answer (score 8):

Let's take a look:

```
>>> help(nltk.translate.bleu_score.corpus_bleu)
Help on function corpus_bleu in module nltk.translate.bleu_score:

corpus_bleu(list_of_references, hypotheses, weights=(0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25), smoothing_function=None)
    Calculate a single corpus-level BLEU score (aka. system-level BLEU) for all 
    the hypotheses and their respective references.  

    Instead of averaging the sentence level BLEU scores (i.e. marco-average 
    precision), the original BLEU metric (Papineni et al. 2002) accounts for 
    the micro-average precision (i.e. summing the numerators and denominators
    for each hypothesis-reference(s) pairs before the division).
    ...
```

You're in a better position than me to understand the description of the algorithm, so I won't try to "explain" it to you.  If the docstring does not clear things up enough, take a look at [the source](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/translate/bleu_score.html#sentence_bleu) itself. Or find it locally:

```
>>> nltk.translate.bleu_score.__file__
'.../lib/python3.4/site-packages/nltk/translate/bleu_score.py'
```

Comment: Very nice, should have looked at source code. Helped me understand a lot