# python regex to split on certain patterns with skip patterns

Tags: python, regex

I want to split a Python string on certain patterns but not others. For example, I have the string

```
Joe, Dave, Professional, Ph.D. and Someone else
```

I want to split on `\sand\s` and `,`, but not `, Ph.D.`

How can this be accomplished in Python regex?

Comment: Could you clarify a little bit what exactly it is you're trying to accomplish at the end of things here? Are you trying to get it to return a split-up string with the things you mentioned as delimiters or what? I'm sorry, it's a little unclear to me. From what I'm gleaning from it, though, you might be able to do this with Python's str.split() method.

Comment: I'm looking for an re or str.split() method to split the above into ['Joe', 'Dave', 'Professional, Ph.D.', 'Someone else']

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059559/python-strings-split-with-multiple-separators

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
re.split(r'\s+and\s+|,(?!\s*Ph\.D\.)\s*', 'Joe, Dave, Professional, Ph.D. and Someone else')
```

Result:

```
['Joe', 'Dave', 'Professional, Ph.D.', 'Someone else']
```

Comment: This gives 'Professional, Ph.D.' as one element where as they are actually two : Professional and Ph.D.

Comment: @GopalChitalia if you read the question you will see that this answer was exactly what was asked for: *"I want to split on `\sand\s` and `,`, but not `, Ph.D.`"*

Comment: umm okay! My bad, sorry for that.

Can you tell me a regex though on how to take into consideration all that? 
Like I have a very large string and I want to tokenize into single words. since I can't split it using just space, as it many patterns.

Example: ( just giving examples of what all kinds of patterns exist. ) 
`''Anarchism'' , U.S.A , from_the_Encyclopaedia ,  [[Hierarchy|hierarchical]], , {{Redirect|Anarchists}} , year=2005, 0-7546-6196-2,http://web.archive.org` 

basically a very large string with all kinds of patterns we can think of and I want to tokenize them.can you help?

Comment: @GopalChitalia isn't not clear to me exactly what you want here. Split on `,`? But just make a new question for this with all the details.

Answer (score 0):

You can basically do this with either regular expressions or just regular
string manipulation operations, (i.e. `str.split()`)

Here's an example that shows you how to do this using just regular string
manipulation operations:

```
>>> DATA = 'Joe, Dave, Professional, Ph.D. and Someone else'
>>> IGNORE_THESE = frozenset([',', 'and'])

>>> PRUNED_DATA = [d.strip(',') for d in DATA.split(' ') if d not in IGNORE_THESE]
>>>> print PRUNED_DATA
['Joe', 'Dave', 'Professional', 'Ph.D.', 'Someone', 'else']
```

I'm sure there is going to be some complex regular expression you can use, but this seems very straight forward for me and quite maintainable.

I hope you're not trying to parse natural language, for that, I would use some other library like [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/)

Comment: **'Someone'** and **'else'** are splitted while OP want to obtain **'Someone else'**

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

DATA = 'Joe, Dave, Professional, Ph.D. and Someone else'

regx = re.compile('\s*(?:,|and)\s*')

print regx.split(DATA)
```

result

```
['Joe', 'Dave', 'Professional', 'Ph.D.', 'Someone else']
```

Where's the difficulty ?

Note that with `(?:,|and)` the delimiters don't appear in the result, while with `(;|and)` the result would be

```
['Joe', ',', 'Dave', ',', 'Professional', ',', 'Ph.D.', 'and', 'Someone else']
```

### Edit 1

errrr.... the difficulty is that with

```
DATA = 'Joe, Dave, Professional, Handicaped, Ph.D. and Someone else'
```

the result is

```
['Joe', 'Dave', 'Professional', 'H', 'icaped', 'Ph.D.', 'Someone else']
```

.

Corrected:

```
regx = re.compile('\s+and\s+|\s*,\s*')
```

.

### Edit 2

errrr.. ahem... ahem...

Sorry, I hadn't noticed that **Professional, Ph.D.** must not be splitted. But what is the criterion to not split according the comma in this string ?

I choosed this criterion: "a comma not followed by a string having dots before the next comma"

Another problem is if whitespaces and word 'and' are mixed.

And there's also the problem of heading and trailing whitespaces.

Finally I succeeded to write a regex' pattern that manages much more cases than the previous one, even if some cases are somewhat artificial (like lost 'and' present at the end of a string; why not at the beginning too, also ? etc) :

```
import re

regx = re.compile('\s*,(?!(?:[^,.]+?\.)+[^,.]*?,)(?:\sand[,\s]+|\s)*|\s*and[,\s]+|[.\s]*\Z|\A\s*')

DATA = '   Joe ,and, Dave , Professional, Ph.D., Handicapped   and handyman  , and   Someone else  and  . .'
print repr(DATA)
print
print regx.split(DATA)
```

result

```
'   Joe ,and, Dave , Professional, Ph.D., Handicapped   and handyman  , and   Someone else  and  . .'

['', 'Joe', '', 'Dave', 'Professional, Ph.D.', 'Handicapped', 'handyman', 'Someone else', '', '']
```

.

With `print [x for x in regx.split(DATA) if x]` , we obtain:

```
['Joe', 'Dave', 'Professional, Ph.D.', 'Handicapped', 'handyman', 'Someone else']
```

.

Compared to result of Qtax's regex on the same string:

```
['   Joe ', 'and', 'Dave ', 'Professional, Ph.D.', 'Handicapped', 'handyman  ', 'and   Someone else', '. .']
```