# Parsing Sentences (or other longer strings) in Python (ProblemSetQuestion) How to proceed?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Alright, so I have unsuccessfully searched the website for parsing long strings (or sentences if you prefer) in Python. If there is a previously answered question of the same nature please redirect me to it! Anyways, Hi! I'm a beginner programmer (self-teaching Python using the internet) and I am looking for help with a (seemingly easy) problem. If you have any input for this problem please don't hesitate to answer the question as you see fit but it would truly help me if you explained your solution(s) or coding examples to me with a bit of depth! Furthermore, my only idea to solve this problem is removing all puntuation using ascii values will one very long if statement then splitting the remaining text by using the spaces left over while appending them to a list. In an effort to save your time and for me to learn something new I'd rather not see the longest expression statement ever! Also please remember that this is a function that returns a list so don't bother converting it (back) into a string or into a different data type such as a dictionary. Thanks in advance for any help you provide!

Without further ado here is the question:

---

> **Parse a string**
>
> Create a function that takes a string as input and returns a list of all words in the >string. It should remove all punctuation, replacing dashes with spaces.

---

Examples(calls):

```
    >>> parse("Listen, strange women lyin' in ponds distributin' swords is no basis for a system of government. Supreme executive power derives from a mandate from the masses, not from some farcical aquatic ceremony.") 
   [Listen, strange, women, lyin, in, ponds, distributin, swords, is, no, basis, for, a, system, of, government, Supreme, executive, power, derives, from, a, mandate, from, the, masses, not, from, some, farcical, aquatic, ceremony] 
    >>> parse("What... is the air-speed velocity of an unladen swallow?") 
    [What, is, the, air, speed, velocity, of, an, unladen, swallow]
```

---

I am so sorry for the run on code length! Anyways I think you all understand what is supposed to be done just from the question itself. Any suggestions or unique/effective solutions are definitely welcomed! - Winkleson

P.s. So sorry for the run-on sentences and "Walls of Texts". I am a bit chatty... Anyways thanks again for any help!

**PLEASE NOTE THAT THE OUTPUT IS NOT A LIST! FURTHERMORE SYMBOLS CANNOT BE INCLUDED IN THE ANSWER! PLEASE DON'T FORGET THAT! THANKS AGAIN FOR YOUR HELP! SORRY FOR THE INCONVIENECE THE AUTHOR OF THE QUESTION MISMATCHED THE ANSWER!**

Comment: You say your output isn't a list, except under "Parse a String", you say it should return a list.  Which is it?

Comment: It isn't a list in the answer. In the example it showed returning a list but the author of the question must have made a mistake!

Comment: These strings aren't particularly long. When poeple speak of "long" strings, they usually mean those that are many megabytes or even gigabytes in size, that would be a challenge to read entirely into memory.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire Sorry for the confusion I'll change the title to sentances :) Sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extracting words from a string, removing punctuation and returning a list with separated words in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7633274/extracting-words-from-a-string-removing-punctuation-and-returning-a-list-with-s)

Comment: @robmayoff I never found this in my searches :P Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a [regular expression](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html), like this

```
import re

re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z]+',input_string)
```

Or for doing multiple strings, compile the regex first

```
regexp=re.compile(r'[a-zA-Z]+')
regexp.findall(test)
```

Essentially, this is asking for all of the characters that contain letters, grouped by characters. If you wanted to, say, include contracted words, you could just add ' to the expression, like this:

```
re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z']+',input_string)
```

Comment: @Peasrsonartphoto was is the re method? I have never heard of it :P Also some more explanation would be nice I'm still a beginner and I don't understand that expression :S

Comment: re=regular expression. Most programming languages support some variant of them, and they are extremely powerful. I've included a link to the python docs on regular expressions (regex for short). I recommend you learn them, as they are extremely powerful for this kind of stuff.

Comment: Thanks alot! This does seem like a much simpler method of solving the problem! Of course it does have to imput a method (I prefer not to unless it's nessesary) but thanks for the answer! (Hey, I learned somethign new and very helpful I'll try to solve the problem with use of the code. Any ideas on how to set the output to the specific call (See calls/examples)?

Comment: Just return what was called, ie, `return re.findall(...)` You do need to input a library, but it is one that is installed with Python by default, so...

Comment: Though it takes care of `'-'`, it won't deal properly with words like `would've`.

Comment: @Pearsonartphoto would that return a list?

Comment: It sure would. Give it a shot.

Comment: @Pearsonartphoto That's kinda the problem it should return in this format (for reasons explained to jdotjdot): [s,s,s,s] not: ['s','s','s','s']. Any suggestions to reformat it correctly or is it not possible to return it in that format? IE: Is it a datatype not defined by the standard python library?

Comment: The list is a list of strings. You could always print it by something like `" ".join(list_strings)`

Comment: I'll try that. I don't understand how he could end up with a format so similar to a list :S Anyways thanks again for your answer! I understand how to do it now (which is the important thing) even if the author's examples != answers. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

It's really easy using the [Natural Language Toolkit (nltk)](http://nltk.org/).

```
import nltk, string
text = "Listen, strange women lyin' in ponds distributin' swords is no basis for a system of government. Supreme executive power derives from a mandate from the masses, not from some farcical aquatic ceremony."

tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(text)

# remove punctuation
tokens = [word.replace("-"," ") for word in tokens if word not in string.punctuation]
```

In use:

```
>>> text = "Listen, strange women lyin' in ponds distributin' swords is no basis
 for a system of government. Supreme executive power derives from a mandate from
 the masses, not from some farcical aquatic ceremony."
>>> tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
>>> tokens = [word.replace("-"," ") for word in tokens if word not in string.punctuation]
>>> tokens
['Listen', 'strange', 'women', 'lyin', 'in', 'ponds', 'distributin', 'swords', '
is', 'no', 'basis', 'for', 'a', 'system', 'of', 'government.', 'Supreme', 'execu
tive', 'power', 'derives', 'from', 'a', 'mandate', 'from', 'the', 'masses', 'not
', 'from', 'some', 'farcical', 'aquatic', 'ceremony']
```

Apparently, your desired output is pretty unclear, but if you're looking for a string version of that output, you could take that `tokens` variable and do:

```
print '[' + ', '.join(tokens) + ']'
```

Looks like:

```
>>> print '['+', '.join(tokens)+']'
[Listen, strange, women, lyin, in, ponds, distributin, swords, is, no, basis, fo
r, a, system, of, government., Supreme, executive, power, derives, from, a, mand
ate, from, the, masses, not, from, some, farcical, aquatic, ceremony]
```

Your "walls of text" do make it hard to figure out what you want.

Comment: This won't work due to the symbol's left in the string's and as it actually has the symbols called. Also the list output is incorrect :P

Comment: Yeah I just caught the puncutation requirement now, fixing that.  Easy to fix.  But what do you mean the output is incorrect?

Comment: It should not return a list. I don't know if it's a tuple or not but it should return in this format: [Listen, strange, women, lyin, in, ponds, distributin, swords, is, no, basis, for, a, system, of, government, Supreme, executive, power, derives, from, a, mandate, from, the, masses, not, from, some, farcical, aquatic, ceremony]. It's different from my example's/calls as well. The author must have screwed that up sorry for the inconvienence!

Comment: That format you gave just now IS a list.  It's a list of strings.  That's what the answers so far have returned.

Comment: please re-read my comment I just edited the main post with the correct output. As I stated the visual solution and Actual solution were completely different. http://singpath.appspot.com has these kinds of issues all the time :S Sorry for the inconvienence!

Comment: You're going to have to explain better, all I see is `[word, word, word]` which looks and smells like a list.

Comment: The problem is the quotations between the strings and the commas they should not exist :S (Well actually it should accept a list but the author of the question messed up his answer by not matching it up with his examples)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19840/discussion-between-jdotjdot-and-winkleson)

Comment: Thanks for including the concatenation of strings to match the desired output!

Answer (score 2):

```
In [133]: punc = set('.,<>!@#$%^&*()-_+=]}{[\\|')

In [134]: [''.join(char for char in word if char not in punc) for word in "Listen, strange women lyin' in ponds distributin' swords is no basis for a system of government. Supreme executive power derives from a mandate from the masses, not from some farcical aquatic ceremony.".split()]
Out[134]: 
['Listen',
 'strange',
 'women',
 "lyin'",
 'in',
 'ponds',
 "distributin'",
 'swords',
 'is',
 'no',
 'basis',
 'for',
 'a',
 'system',
 'of',
 'government',
 'Supreme',
 'executive',
 'power',
 'derives',
 'from',
 'a',
 'mandate',
 'from',
 'the',
 'masses',
 'not',
 'from',
 'some',
 'farcical',
 'aquatic',
 'ceremony']
```

Comment: That would be deemed incorrect due to the symbols left inside the strings! Nice try though :P

Comment: Yeah I just caught that. I didn't get that directly from the question's description. Working on a patch right now ;]

Comment: Thanks alot :D If it was as easy as splitting the variable I think I would cry a little (nearly did). My problem is removing the symbols without a large if statement below splitting :) It would be good to see as many methods as possible to obtain the same solution though!

Comment: @Winkleson: I was wondering why you were asking such a seemingly simple question. But that was before I saw that the punctuation was missing from the answer :). Sorry about the confusion in the first post

Comment: No problem I understand completely if you skimmed my super long post :P So you just condensed the loops/statement to include a set of all special character's? Seems easy enough :D Thanks!

Comment: Oh go this didn't work it seems that what is returned is: [s, s, s, s] instead of: ['s', 's', 's'] Please help!

Comment: @Winkleson: I don't follow. It works on your sample input, and I don't understand your last comment