# extracting words from a string without using the .split() function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I coded this in order to get a list full of a given string words .

```
data=str(input("string"))
L=[]
word=""
for i in data:
    if i.isalpha() :
        word+=i
    elif :
        L.append(word)
        word=""
```

but, when I run this code it doesn't show the last word !

Comment: Where exactly would you expect the code to show anything? Please, as a new user here, take the [tour] and read [ask], you are being very unspecific. BTW: check the documentation for `input()` in Python 3, you should find a small optimization opportunity for your code.

Comment: You don't see the last word in the list because when you reach the last char of the string, you break out of the loop and the `L.append(word)` statement does not get executed. You can solve this by adding the `L.append(word)` statement after this loop. However, as @UlrichEckhardt stated, there is a much simpler way to achieve what you are trying to do using the `split` method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extracting words from a string, removing punctuation and returning a list with separated words in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7633274/extracting-words-from-a-string-removing-punctuation-and-returning-a-list-with-s)

Comment: You added "... without using split()". Any more restrictions? Please make sure to [edit] your question and list them. That said, there cannot be a good reason to avoid built-in functions...

Comment: @LakshayGarg, thanks that's what I was looking for .

Answer (score 0):

You can simply split words on a string using `str.split()` method, here is a demo:

```
data = input("string: ")
words = data.split()
L = []

for word in words:
    if word.isalpha():
        L.append(word)
print(L)
```

Note that `.split()` splits a string by any whitespace character by default, if you want for example to split using commas instead, you can simply use `data.split(",")`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,I need to use .isalpha() function I tried but the last word doesn't appear in the list .

Comment: Why do you even cast string to string? input() returns  as string

Comment: @Rarblack oh, yes thank you, I actually copied that line of code.

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting the last word into the list because it does not have non-alpha character to make it pass to the else stage and save the word to list.

Let's correct your code a little. I assume you want to check the words in the string but not characters(because what you are doing right now is checking each charackter not words.):

```
data=input("Input the string: ") #you don't need to cast string to string (input() returns string)
data = data+' ' # to make it save the last word
l=[] #variable names should be lowercase
word=""
for i in data:
    if i.isalpha() :
        word+=i         
    else:  # you shouldn't use elif it is else if no condition is provided
        l.append(word)
        word=" " # not to make each word connected right after each other
```