# How to find the frequency of a word in a text file using python? But user should give the input word

Tags: python, python-3.x

My aim:
To count the frequency of a user entered word in a text file.(in python)
I tried this.But it gives the frequency of all the words in the file.How can i modify it to give the frequency of a word entered by the user?

```
from collections import Counter
word=input("Enter a word:")
def word_count(test6):
        with open('test6.txt') as f:
                return Counter(f.read().split())

print("Number of input words in the file :",word_count(word))
```

This may be a naive question but I am just beginning to code.So please try to answer.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well first you will need to use `input()` to allow the user to give you the word they are interested in. then you can look for that word in your Counter

Comment: I used input() to give the input.But still, it's displaying the count of all words.

Comment: Please update your code to show that. but you will also just want to print the word from the counter not all the counts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to find the frequency of a word in a file you can just join all the lines from your file using `str.join` and then just use `str.count`:

```
def word_count(word):
    with open('test6.txt') as f:
            return ''.join(f).count(word)


print("Number of words in the file :", word_count(input('give me a word')))
```

also you may use for word count in the text:

```
def word_count(word):
        with open('test6.txt') as f:
                return f.read().count(word)
```

Answer (score 1):

While str.count works nice if you only look up one word, the approach with `Counter` is better when you want to get multiple word-counts and have a bigger text to search through (say a whole book, some megabyte of data).

In that case you can read your book once into a `Counter` and query it multiple times. You need to clean up data though, f.e. newlines and punctation have to be removed so you find `'so'` inside `'Is that so?'`:

```
import string
from collections import Counter
# fixed text, normally you read your file here
text = """This text has punctation
as well as newlines. No -word- will
be unaccounted for. This text should do
as test text for now. no no no"""

# make a translation to remove punctuation and newlines from the text
# before splitting it into words that you then count once
punct = string.punctuation
p = str.maketrans(punct + "\n\r", ' '*(len(punct)+2))

wc = Counter(text.translate(p).split())

# repeatedly ask your counter how often the word occured
while True:
    word=input("Enter a word: ") 
    if not word.strip():
        break 
    print(f"'{word}' occures {wc.get(word,0)} times.")
```

Output:

```
Enter a word: text
'text' occures 3 times.
Enter a word: has
'has' occures 1 times.
Enter a word: do
'do' occures 1 times.
Enter a word: no
'no' occures 3 times.
Enter a word:
```

If you can do regex, you could also extract words by regex, more here: [Extracting words from a string, removing punctuation and returning a list with separated words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7633274/extracting-words-from-a-string-removing-punctuation-and-returning-a-list-with-s)

Comment: @kederra now it will. And counter has a use if you have a bigger text and want to get multiple word counts from it without rereading the text from the file over and over again. for a one time count your solution is fine.