# python split string on multiple delimeters without regex

Tags: python, string, split

I have a string that I need to split on multiple characters **without** the use of regular expressions.  for example, I would need something like the following:

```
>>>string="hello there[my]friend"
>>>string.split(' []')
['hello','there','my','friend']
```

is there anything in python like this?

Comment: You will have to use replace with split if you want to avoid regex.  Is this a homework?

Comment: no, this is not homework. the reason to avoid regex is simply that I do not really know regex

Comment: I would suggest to try some regex tutorial (like [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)), because regular expressions are really usefull and easy to use in python.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you need multiple delimiters, `re.split` is the way to go.

Without using a regex, it's not possible unless you write a custom function for it.

Here's such a function - it might or might not do what you want (consecutive delimiters cause empty elements):

```
>>> def multisplit(s, delims):
...     pos = 0
...     for i, c in enumerate(s):
...         if c in delims:
...             yield s[pos:i]
...             pos = i + 1
...     yield s[pos:]
...
>>> list(multisplit('hello there[my]friend', ' []'))
['hello', 'there', 'my', 'friend']
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution without regexp:

```
from itertools import groupby
sep = ' []'
s = 'hello there[my]friend'
print [''.join(g) for k, g in groupby(s, sep.__contains__) if not k]
```

I've just posted an explanation here https://stackoverflow.com/a/19211729/2468006

Answer (score 1):

A recursive solution without use of regex. Uses only base python in contrast to the other answers.

```
def split_on_multiple_chars(string_to_split, set_of_chars_as_string):
    # Recursive splitting
    # Returns a list of strings

    s = string_to_split
    chars = set_of_chars_as_string

    # If no more characters to split on, return input
    if len(chars) == 0:
        return([s])

    # Split on the first of the delimiter characters
    ss = s.split(chars[0])

    # Recursive call without the first splitting character
    bb = []
    for e in ss:
        aa = split_on_multiple_chars(e, chars[1:])
        bb.extend(aa)
    return(bb)
```

Works very similarly to pythons regular `string.split(...)`, but accepts several delimiters.

Example use:

```
print(split_on_multiple_chars('my"example_string.with:funny?delimiters', '_.:;'))
```

Output:

```
['my"example', 'string', 'with', 'funny?delimiters']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not worried about long strings, you could force all delimiters to be the same using string.replace(). The following splits a string by both `-` and `,`

`x.replace('-', ',').split(',')`

If you have many delimiters you could do the following:

```
def split(x, delimiters):
    for d in delimiters:
        x = x.replace(d, delimiters[0])
    return x.split(delimiters[0])
```

Answer (score -3):

[`re.split`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.split) is the right tool here.

```
>>> string="hello there[my]friend"
>>> import re
>>> re.split('[] []', string)
['hello', 'there', 'my', 'friend']
```

In regex, `[...]` defines a character class. Any characters inside the brackets will match. The way I've spaced the brackets avoids needing to escape them, but the pattern `[\[\] ]` also works.

```
>>> re.split('[\[\] ]', string)
['hello', 'there', 'my', 'friend']
```

The `re.DEBUG` flag to re.compile is also useful, as it prints out what the pattern will match:

```
>>> re.compile('[] []', re.DEBUG)
in 
  literal 93
  literal 32
  literal 91
<_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x16b0850>
```

(Where 32, 91, 93, are the ascii values assigned to , `[`, `]`)