# get list of what was not matched by regex?

Tags: python, regex

I am splitting a string using "[Python strings split with multiple separators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059559/python-strings-split-with-multiple-separators)":

```
import re
DATA = "Hey, you - what are you doing here!?"
print re.findall(r'\w+', DATA)
# Prints ['Hey', 'you', 'what', 'are', 'you', 'doing', 'here']
```

I want to get a separate list of of what's in between the matched words:

```
[", ", " - ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "!?"]
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
print re.findall(r'\W+', DATA)  # note, UPPER-case "W"
```

yields the list you are looking for:

```
[', ', ' - ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '!?']
```

I used `\W+` rather than `\w+` which negates the character class you were using.

```
   \w  Matches word characters, i.e., letters, digits, and underscores.
   \W  Matches non-word characters, i.e., the negated version of \w
```

This [Regular Expression Reference Sheet](http://networking.ringofsaturn.com/Web/regex.php) might be helpful in selecting the best character classes/meta characters for your regular expression searches/matches. Also, see this [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_reg_expressions.htm) for more information (esp the reference section toward the bottom of the page)

Answer (score 3):

How about using the complementary regex to `\w`, `\W`? Also, instead of getting a separate list, it's probably more efficient to get it all at once. (Although of course it depends what you intend to do with it.)

```
>>> re.findall(r'(\w+)(\W+)', DATA)
[('Hey', ', '), ('you', ' - '), ('what', ' '), ('are', ' '), ('you', ' '), ('doing', ' '), ('here', '!?')]
```

If you really want separate lists, just zip it:

```
>>> zip(*re.findall(r'(\w+)(\W+)', DATA))
[('Hey', 'you', 'what', 'are', 'you', 'doing', 'here'), (', ', ' - ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '!?')]
```

Answer (score 0):

[re](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html).split

```
import re
DATA = "Hey, you - what are you doing here!?"
print re.split(r'\w+', DATA)
#prints ['', ', ', ' - ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '!?']
```

You might also want to filter out empty strings to match what you asked for exactly.