# Multi symbol string splitter in python?

Tags: python, regex, split

I have a string, let's say `"MDP-A-17_MDP-A-23.3"`. I want this string split based on `"-"`, `"_"` and `"."`.

The output will be a list:

```
["MDP", "A", "17", "MDP", "A", "23", "3"]
```

Comment: excellent question, so +1, but it has been asked a bunch of times already.  e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059559/python-strings-split-with-multiple-separators

Comment: Okay. yeah looks so. I might have missed it. Thanks for pointing to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pretty sure you can use re.split, as your question suggests...

```
import re    
s = "MDP-A-17_MDP-A-23.3"
l = re.split(r'[-_.]',s)
```

Check the docs... http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Comment: By the way, that is the most emotive regular expression I've ever made. :)

Comment: @AashishP You should mark this as an accepted answer. :)