# Trying to count words in a string

Tags: python, string, list, function, loops

I'm trying to analyze the contents of a string. If it has a punctuation mixed in the word I want to replace them with spaces.

For example, If Johnny.Appleseed!is:a*good&farmer is entered as an input then it should say there are 6 words, but my code only sees it as 0 words. I'm not sure how to remove an incorrect character.

FYI: I'm using python 3, also I can't import any libraries

```
string = input("type something")
stringss = string.split()

    for c in range(len(stringss)):
        for d in stringss[c]:
            if(stringss[c][d].isalnum != True):
                #something that removes stringss[c][d]
                total+=1
print("words: "+ str(total))
```

Comment: You are over-complicating this. You can iterate a string using a normal for loop.

Comment: `d` is an individual character of a string, *not* and index. And you are not calling the `.isalnum()` method, just referencing it. And use `if not` to test for negative, not `!= True`.

Comment: And why can't you import any libraries...?

Comment: I was told not to use it. What's wrong with using != True?

Comment: @HarryHarry It's not Pythonic. And just because you are using Python 3, does not mean you cannot import any libraries. If that were true, Python 3 would probably not have been released.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Simple loop based solution:

```
strs = "Johnny.Appleseed!is:a*good&farmer"
lis = []
for c in strs:
    if c.isalnum() or c.isspace():
        lis.append(c)
    else:
        lis.append(' ')

new_strs = "".join(lis)
print new_strs           #print 'Johnny Appleseed is a good farmer'
new_strs.split()         #prints ['Johnny', 'Appleseed', 'is', 'a', 'good', 'farmer']
```

## Better solution:

Using `regex`:

```
>>> import re
>>> from string import punctuation
>>> strs = "Johnny.Appleseed!is:a*good&farmer"
>>> r = re.compile(r'[{}]'.format(punctuation))
>>> new_strs = r.sub(' ',strs)
>>> len(new_strs.split())
6
#using `re.split`:
>>> strs = "Johnny.Appleseed!is:a*good&farmer"
>>> re.split(r'[^0-9A-Za-z]+',strs)
['Johnny', 'Appleseed', 'is', 'a', 'good', 'farmer']
```

Comment: How's regex a better solution, is it faster?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams You're right about that(`re.sub` and then `str.split` eh!!), I guess `re.split` is a better alternative.

Comment: `>>> len(re.findall(r'\b\w+\b', 'Johnny.Appleseed!is:a*good&farmer'))`
`6`

Comment: If you're going to use `re.split`, then I'd go for `re.split('[\W]+', strs)`... but I'd rather the more direct `re.findall` as shown by @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams

Comment: @JonClements I think it should be `'[\W_]+'`? Anyways thanks for the useful tip. :) I should work hard on regexes.

Answer (score 11):

Here's a one-line solution that doesn't require importing any libraries.
It replaces non-alphanumeric characters (like punctuation) with spaces, and then `split`s the string.

Inspired from "[Python strings split with multiple separators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059559/python-strings-split-with-multiple-separators)"

```
>>> s = 'Johnny.Appleseed!is:a*good&farmer'
>>> words = ''.join(c if c.isalnum() else ' ' for c in s).split()
>>> words
['Johnny', 'Appleseed', 'is', 'a', 'good', 'farmer']
>>> len(words)
6
```

Answer (score 3):

try this: it parses the word_list using re, then creates a dictionary of word:appearances

```
import re
word_list = re.findall(r"[\w']+", string)
print {word:word_list.count(word) for word in word_list}
```

Answer (score 3):

How about using Counter from collections ?

```
import re
from collections import Counter

words = re.findall(r'\w+', string)
print (Counter(words))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for ltr in ('!', '.', ...) # insert rest of punctuation
     stringss = strings.replace(ltr, ' ')
return len(stringss.split(' '))
```

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is an old question but...How about this?

```
string = "If Johnny.Appleseed!is:a*good&farmer"

a = ["*",":",".","!",",","&"," "]
new_string = ""

for i in string:
   if i not in a:
      new_string += i
   else:
      new_string = new_string  + " "

print(len(new_string.split(" ")))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#Write a python script to count words in a given string.
 s=str(input("Enter a string: "))
 words=s.split()
 count=0
  for word in words:
      count+=1

  print(f"total number of words in the string is : {count}")
```