# How do I fix this program so I can count the number of letters and how do I count words?

Tags: python

How do I fix this program so I can count the number of letters and how do I count words?

```
import collections as c
text = input('Enter text')
print(len(text))
a = len(text)
counts = c.Counter(a)
print(counts)
spaces = counts(' ')
print(specific)
print(a-spaces)
#I want to count the number of letters so I want the amount of characters - the amount of             
#spaces.
```

Comment: You might want to store the `len(text)` first then use the variable.

Comment: See this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17507876/trying-to-count-words-in-a-string-python

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the string directly to the constructor of Counter

```
cc = c.Counter( "this is a test" )
cc[" "] # will be 3
```

To do words, just split on spaces (or maybe periods too_

```
cc = c.Counter( "this is a test test".split( " " ) )
cc[ "test" ] # will be 2
```

Answer (score 0):

To count characters, you can use regular expressions to remove any non-alphanumeric character, i.e.:

```
import re
print(re.sub("[\W]", "", text))
```

You can use the `re` module to count words too, by counting the non-empty strings you get from splitting the string at non-alphanumeric characters:

```
print([word for word in re.split("[\W]", text) if len(word) > 0])
```

If you want to strip numbers too, just use `[\W\d]` instead of `[\W]`.

You can find more on regular expressions [here](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html).

Answer (score 0):

Don't go over your head with this one and use a good old list comprehension:

```
text = raw_input('Enter text') #or input(...) if you're using python 3.X
number_of_non_spaces = len([i for i in text if i != " "])
number_of_spaces = len(text) - number_of_non_spaces
```