# TypeError: expected a character buffer object # when i split

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
def split_string(source,splitlist):
    sl = list(splitlist)
    new = source.split(sl)
    return new
```

When i run it:

```
print split_string("This is a test-of the,string separation-code!"," ,!-")
```

I have the following error:

```
new = source.split(sl)
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

How can I fix this?

**Note:** first i want to make a list from `splitlist` than i want split `source` with every element in my `sl` list.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python strings split with multiple separators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059559/python-strings-split-with-multiple-separators)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're looking for something like

```
import re
def multisplit(s, delims):
    delims = '|'.join(re.escape(x) for x in delims)
    return re.split(delims, s)

print multisplit('a.b-c!d', '.-!') # ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

`str.split` doesn't accept a list of separators, although I wish it did, just like `endswith`.

Answer (score 2):

The argument to `str.split` must be a string, not a `list` of possible separators.

Answer (score 0):

With no additional libraries you could do:

```
def split_string(source,splitlist):
    ss = list(source)
    sl = list(splitlist)
    new = ''.join([o if not o in sl else ' ' for o in ss]).split()
    return new
```