# Is it possible to split a string on multiple delimiters in order?

Tags: python, regex, string

I know how to split a string based on multiple separators using re as in this question: [Split Strings with Multiple Delimiters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059559/python-strings-split-with-multiple-separators?lq=1). But I'm wondering how to split a string using the order given in a list of delimiters where each split would only happen once.

```
multiple_sep_split("hello^goo^dbye:cat@dog", ['^',':','@'])
>>> ['hello', 'goo^dbye', 'cat', 'dog']  #(note the extra carat)
multiple_sep_split("my_cat:my_dog:my:bird_my_python",[':',':','_'])
>>> ['my_cat','my_dog','my:bird','my_python']
```

One approach could be to match not on the delimiters but on the text in between the delimiters and return those as groups but is there another way?

```
text_re = re.compile('(.+)^(.+):(.+)@(.+)') # get each group from here
```

Comment: Are you asking for a better method than the regex you gave? Is there something wrong with it?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking for.  Putting "in order" in italics doesn't actually *explain* what it means to you ;-)  The example at the start *might* be helpful if you specified the set (list?) of separators you had in mind - as-is, we can only guess.

Comment: I'll update it now! Had to go to lunch...!

Comment: @TimPeters Thanks for your efforts in trying to understand the question! I've updated it so that it hopefully makes more sense :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking, you just want a series of string `partition` operations: first `partition` on the first separator, then the second, etc to the end.

Here's a recursive method (which doesn't use re):

```
def splits(s,seps):
    l,_,r = s.partition(seps[0])
    if len(seps) == 1:
        return [l,r]
    return [l] + splits(r,seps[1:])
```

demo:

```
a = 'hello^goo^dbye:cat@dog'

splits(a,['^',':','@'])
Out[7]: ['hello', 'goo^dbye', 'cat', 'dog']
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe your question is severely under-specified, but at least this gives the result you want in the example you gave:

```
def split_at_most_once_each_and_in_order(s, seps):
    result = []
    start = 0
    for sep in seps:
        i = s.find(sep, start)
        if i >= 0:
            result.append(s[start: i])
            start = i+1
    if start < len(s):
        result.append(s[start:])
    return result

print split_at_most_once_each_and_in_order(
    "hello^goo^dbye:cat@dog", "^:@")
```

That returns `['hello', 'goo^dbye', 'cat', 'dog']`.  If you absolutely want to "be clever", keep looking ;-)

Comment: it heartens me to see that we independently arrived at the same variable names.  Though your function name is obviously superior :)

Comment: Obviously:  `splits` can only be applied to bananas ;-)