# how to split brackets using python abcd[00451.00]

Tags: python

I have tried below code to split but I am unable to split

```
import re
s = "abcd[00451.00]"

print str(s).strip('[]')
```

I need output as only number or decimal format 00451.00 this value but I am able to get output as abcd[00451.00

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python strings split with multiple separators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059559/python-strings-split-with-multiple-separators)

Comment: @All who are answering this question.     

When I see a post like this one, I assume that the OP is beginner, so Please avoid one line solutions or please also provide details to the OP about your cool one liners.

Answer (score 2):

If you know for sure that there will be one opening and closing brackets you can do

```
s = "abcd[00451.00]"
print s[s.index("[") + 1:s.rindex("]")]
# 00451.00
```

[`str.index`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.index) is used to get the first index of the element `[` in the string, where as [`str.rindex`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rindex) is used to get the last index of the element in `]`. Based on those indexes, the string is [sliced](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/1903116).

If you want to convert that to a floating point number, then you can use [`float`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#float) function, like this

```
print float(s[s.index("[") + 1:s.rindex("]")])
# 451.0
```

Comment: Please add some explanation too, I don't think OP is very comfortable with your cool one liner. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `re.search`:

```
import re
s = "abcd[00451.00]"

>>> print re.search(r'\[([^\]]+)\]', s).group(1)
00451.00
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first split on the '[' and then strip the resulting list of any ']' chars:

```py
[p.strip(']') for p in s.split('[')]
```