# How to make my code detect end of string in python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write code to split a sentence without it's punctuation. For example, if a user inputs `"Hello, how are you?"`, I can split the sentence to `['hello','how','are','you']`

```
userinput = str(raw_input("Enter your sentence: "))

def sentence_split(sentence):
    result = []
    current_word = ""
    for letter in sentence:
        if letter.isalnum(): 
            current_word += letter     
        else: ## this is a symbol or punctuation, e.g. reach end of a word
            if current_word: 
                result.append(current_word)
                current_word = "" ## reinitialise for creating a new word
    return result

print "Split of your sentence:", sentence_split(userinput)
```

so far my code works, but if i put a sentence without ending it with a punctuation, the last word won't show up in result, for example, if the input were `"Hello, how are you"`, the result would be `['hello','how','are']`, I guess it's because there's no punctuation to tell the code the string is ended, is there a way I can make the program detect it's the end of string? So that even if the input were `"Hello, how are you"`, the result would still be `['hello','how','are','you']`.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059559/python-strings-split-with-multiple-separators/21639500

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've not tried to adjust your algorithm myself, but I think the method below should achieve what you are after.

```
def sentence_split(sentence):
    new_sentence = sentence[:]
    for letter in sentence:
        if not letter.isalnum():
            new_sentence = new_sentence.replace(letter, ' ')
    return new_sentence.split()
```

Now with it running:

runfile(r'C:\Users\cat\test.py', wdir=r'C:\Users\cat')

['Hello', 'how', 'are', 'you']

Edit: Fixed a bug with initialisation of new_sentence.

Comment: Better replace punctuation with spaces. Otherwise you'll merge two words that are only separated by e.g. a comma.

Comment: i thought of doing it with this method before, but this means i have to list all the punctuation i can think of, it might be easier if i can just use str.isalnum() method?

Comment: Ok I'll adjust to suit that

Comment: sorry but when i try your code the result is ['hello,', 'how', 'are', 'you']

Comment: You sure you are trying the above code exactly? Works fine for me.

Comment: Just noticed a bug I found, but I never updated on here. Please try it again.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
def split_string(text, splitlist):
    for sep in splitlist:
        text = text.replace(sep, splitlist[0])
    return filter(None, text.split(splitlist[0])) if splitlist else [text]
```

If you set `splitlist` to `"!?,."` or whatever you need to split on, this will first replace every instance of punctuation with the first `sep` from `splitlist`, and finally will split the whole sentence on the first `sep`, while removing empty strings from the returned list (that's what `filter(None, list)` does).

Or you could use this simple regex solution:

```
>>> s = "Hello, how are you?"
>>> re.findall(r'([A-Za-z]+)', s)
['Hello', 'how', 'are', 'you']
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the algorithm expects every word to end with punctuation or a space, you could just add a space to the end of the input to make sure the algorithm terminates properly:

```
userinput = str(raw_input("Enter your sentence: ")) + " "
```

Result:

```
Enter your sentence: hello how are you
Split of your sentence: ['hello', 'how', 'are', 'you']
```

Answer (score 0):

Method 1:

Why not just use `re.split('[a list of chars i do not like]', s)`?

https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Method 2:

Sanitize string (remove unwanted characters):

http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=1j7ACbyK

Then do `s.split(' ')`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you don’t do anything with `current_word` at the end, unless you hit a non-alphanum character:

```
for letter in sentence:
    if letter.isalnum():
        current_word += letter     
    else:
        if current_word: 
            result.append(current_word)
            current_word = ""
return result
```

If the last letter is another character, it will just be added to `current_word`, but `current_word` will never be appended to the result. You can fix this, by simply duplicating the append-logic after the loop:

```
for letter in sentence:
    if letter.isalnum():
        current_word += letter     
    else:
        if current_word: 
            result.append(current_word)
            current_word = ""

if current_word: 
    result.append(current_word)

return result
```

So now, when `current_word` is non-empty after the loop, it will be appended to the result as well. And in case the last character *was* some punctuation, `current_word` will be empty again, so the condition of the `if` after the loop won’t be true.