# Split() not working?

Tags: python, string, list, split

So I am trying to split a string **s**:

```
s = "l=2&w=3&h=2"
```

However whenever I try to use the *split()* function on s and store the values in list **L**, this comes up:

```
L = s.split()
L --> ['l=2&w=3&h=2']
```

Am I doing something wrong? How do I split this string so I get:

```
L = ['l','=','2','&','w','=','3','&','h','=','2']
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's actually easier than you might think.

```
L = list(s)
```

In Python, strings are iterable, just like lists.  If you just need to iterate over the string, you don't even *need* to store it in a list.

Answer (score 5):

[`split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) with no arguments splits on whitespace, which your string contains none of.  To split on every character, just convert your string directly to a list:

```
L = list(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the whole story. I know .list() will work but I also must say this. If you import the right library, I think, you have another method:

```
    import re
    s = "l=2&w=3&h=2"
    print re.findall(r"[\w']+", s)
    # Prints ['1', '=', '2', '&', 'w', '=', '3', '&', 'h', '=', '2']
```

I got the answer from the following source. It's actually another stack exchange question:

[Split Strings with Multiple Delimiters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059559/python-strings-split-with-multiple-separators)

Not perfect, I know, but I hope it helps.