# Elegant way of temporarily assigning a variable within dictionary comprehension?

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

Out of curiosity is it possible to write the following logic as a nice dict comprehension?

```
a = "a c\nb c\nn q\n".split('\n')[:-1]

output = {}
for line in a:
    tmp = line.split(' ')
    output[tmp[0]] = tmp[1]
```

I wrote the following, but without a temporary assignment I have to split twice which is unfortunate:

```
{line.split(' ')[0]:line.split(' ')[1] for line in a}
```

Is something more elegant possible?

Comment: You could use regex to split by two dilimiters at once:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059559/python-strings-split-with-multiple-delimiters

Comment: What about using the csv package and obtaining a map using csv.DictReader? https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/csv.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a nested list comprehension:

```
{p[0]:p[1] for p in [l.split(" ") for l in a]}
```

Output:

```
{'a': 'c', 'b': 'c', 'n': 'q'}
```

Comment: Thank Guido who designed Python :)

Comment: I like this because this is a common problem I run into with list/dict comprehensions and this generalizes a lot better than many of the other methods, which may be better for this specific case.

Comment: Answer was so obvious, but I missed it. Thank you

Answer (score 7):

In this case, I think the dict *constructor* is a little nicer since it will take an iterable of 2-sequences:

```
dict(line.split() for line in a)
```

Demo:

```
>>> a
['a c', 'b c', 'n q']
>>> dict(line.split() for line in a)
{'a': 'c', 'b': 'c', 'n': 'q'}
```

Comment: It's really a pity that I can't accept two answers because this is actually the best solution for this specific case, but @Tichodroma's answer is more general.

Comment: Darn, I had tried the same with a dict comprehension which didn't work, so I thought `dict()` wouldn't either. Good to know there's a difference here.

Answer (score 2):

Highly specific to the whitespace in your particular input:

```
>>> a = "a c\nb c\nn q\n".split('\n')[:-1]
>>> {line[0]:line[2] for line in a}
{'a': 'c', 'b': 'c', 'n': 'q'}
```

Answer (score 0):

does that work:

```
>>> a = "a c\nb c\nn q\n".split('\n')[:-1]

>>> {i[0]:i[1]  for line in a for i in [line.split(' ')]}
 {'a': 'c', 'b': 'c', 'n': 'q'}
```

Comment: Oops. I made a mistake when defining `a`.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can use

```
dict(line.split(' ') for line in a)
```

but for more complicated "value processing" I usually find it easier to use either "normal" loop (like you did) or write small helper function:

```
def helper(val):
    ...
    return key, value

dict(helper(line) for line in a)
```

This is one thing (crippled lambda/anonymous function syntax) I *really* hate about python.

Answer (score 0):

Use a nested list comprehension without a split.

```
>>> {line[0]:line[-1] for line in a}
{'a': 'c', 'b': 'c', 'n': 'q'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Through python's re module,

```
>>> import re
>>> a = "a c\nb c\nn q\n"
>>> a
'a c\nb c\nn q\n'
>>> m = re.findall(r'^(.) (.)$', a, re.M)
>>> m
[('a', 'c'), ('b', 'c'), ('n', 'q')]
>>> dict(m)
{'a': 'c', 'b': 'c', 'n': 'q'}
```