# Plot sine wave of higher frequencies

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, msp430

I am sending serial data from uart to pc and trying to plot sine wave(**using Python**) sent from function generator through ADC12 of MSP430F5438A.
I am able to plot the wave for lower sampling frequencies(<120Hz) but when I increase the sampling frequency the digits get concatenated i.e. if two values 2563 , 2879 are sent through uart then python reads them as 25632879. So, I am not able to plot the graph as values are not correct.
I am sending the values without new line between them, if I send with new line then the values are not read correctly - python reads them with space in between so then again I get another error: could not convert string to float.
I tried data = ser.readline() as well but no luck
I am attaching the code below.Please see if anything can be done to solve this problem.

```
import sys
import serial
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import deque

port = "COM11"
baud = 9600
timeout=1

ser = serial.Serial()
ser.port = port
ser.baudrate = baud
ser.timeout = timeout


a1 = deque([0.0]*100)
#ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 100), ylim=(0, 1000))



line, = plt.plot(a1)
plt.ion()
plt.ylim([0,1000])

try:
  ser.open()
except:
  sys.stderr.write("Error opening serial port %s\n" % (ser.portstr) )
  sys.exit(1)

#ser.setRtsCts(0)

while 1:
     # Read from serial port, blocking
     data = ser.read(1)

     # If there is more than 1 byte, read the rest
     n = ser.inWaiting()
     data = data + ser.read(n)
     #sys.stdout.write(data)
     print(a1)

     a1.appendleft((data))
     datatoplot = a1.pop()
     line.set_ydata(a1)
     plt.draw()
```

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you send a "," between two values and then in python use this "delimiter" to separate the values? [link to delimiting with python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059559/python-strings-split-with-multiple-delimiters)

p.s. This concept of packet delimiter is useful if you at some point move onto serial communication protocols.

Comment: Thanks, I am now able to plot for higher frequencies but if I use the delimiter for lower sampling frequencies I lose my data and I get 0.0 as output while it should be the value I am receiving from serial port.I think this is because at lower frequencies I do not actually require delimiter as my values are already separated but as in my case when I use delimiter it returns 0 value. so is there a way to make this robust for both lower as well as higher frequencies

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways for doing this reliably:

- **Use a delimiter** . All you need is to parse the value correctly:

  ```
  line = serial.readline()
  reading = int(line)
  ```
- If you don't want to use a delimiter then send a formatted reading from the msp:

  ```
  uint8_t buffer[5];
  snprintf(buffer, 4, "%04d", reading);
  uart_print(buffer);
  ```

  this way you will *always* get 4 characters per reading, so you can do this in the python code:

  ```
  line = serial.read(4)
  reading = int(line)
  ```

I'd still go for the first alternative, though.