# Split list of strings at separator and move separator into own entry in list

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a process that splits a string into tokens. At the moment it looks like this:

```
separators = ['(', ')', '+', '-', '*', '/', '=']

def tokenize(string):
    result_list = string.split()
    print result_list

print tokenize('((2 + 3) / (4 * 22))')
```

Which outputs this:

```
['((2', '+', '3)', '/', '(4', '*', '22))']
```

Which is pretty close, but I need the parentheses split out from the string (i.e., the output above it should read:

```
['(', '(', '2', '+', '3', ')', '/', '(', '4', '*', '22', ')', ')']
```

Any thoughts or help? Thanks!

Comment: `re.findall(r'\w+|[^\w\s]', s)`

Comment: That's not close in ay sense, I guess, you are just using `split()` with nothing as parameter, so it simply splits on the `" "`(whitespaces), To split the given string on something other than white space you must pass that string as parameter to the `split()`, or if you want to split on multiple strings then you should use `regex`

Comment: it can be done with regexp, but it's not the way to do it. I suggest you read http://ruslanspivak.com/lsbasi-part1/ tutorial by Ruslan Spivak, it shows good examples of how to achieve what you want.

Comment: I suggest reading this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059559/python-split-strings-with-multiple-delimiters as it contains the answer that you need.

Comment: What exactly you are trying to do? We may be able to help you better. Are you trying to parse the string as small valid expressions?

Comment: Yeah, I am. I made a mistake with the split method, I realise now, since the args I submitted to the process had whitespace. The article @pythad linked is helpful, and the answer below with `re` works perfectly. Would like to cross-check validity in its output against my separators list though.

Comment: @CD-RUM .. are you trying to evaluate that string into a valid expression?..if that's the case there are other easier ways to do it that using `split` or `regex` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do

```
import re
x="((2 + 3) / (4 * 22))"
print [i for i in re.split("(\W)",x) if i!=" " and i]
```

Output:`['(', '(', '2', '+', '3', ')', '/', '(', '4', '*', '22', ')', ')']`

or

```
x="((2 + 3) / (4 * 22))"
print [i for i in re.split("((?! )\W)| ",x) if i]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **\S** regex.

**\S** => `match any non-white space character.`

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'[\S]')
test_str = u"((2 + 3) / (4 * 22))"

print re.findall(p, test_str)
```

**Output** - `['(', '(', '2', '+', '3', ')', '/', '(', '4', '*', '22', ')', ')']`

Comment: what is `ur` in `p = re.compile(ur'[\S]')` statement?