# How to remove a footnote from markdown with Python

Tags: python, regex, markdown

I'm a regex novice. I have some strings in Python like this: `^b^[word](#30b)` from markdown text. I would like to strip the footnote to get just the word.

I have the following working:

```
import re
pattern = r"\[([\w]+)\]"
s = "^b^[word](#32b)"
m = re.search(pattern, s)
print(m.group(1))
```

That snippet extracts the word `word`. But now what if I have multiple words inside the brackets like: `^c^[every word](#12c)` and I want to extract all the words? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this: `\^[^^]+\^\[([^\]]+)\]\([^)]+\)`

The code will be like:

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'\^[^^]+\^\[([^\]]+)\]\([^)]+\)')
test_str = u"^b^[word another words](#30b)"


for (words) in re.findall(p, test_str):
    print words.split()
```

The regex isn't very complicated, it just involves a lot of escaping.

- `[^^]+` matches some characters that aren't `^`
- `([^\]]+)` captures the inside of the brackets
- `[^)]+` matches characters that aren't `)`

---

I have only provided a simple split for the words.

You can find more complex solutions [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059559)

Comment: @TJB You gave too little data for me to know that not all foot notes start with `^b^`. I have fixed this, and added some instructions for how to get an array of words. Please don't change the question, and instead ask a new one in the future.

Comment: Sorry bout that! ;-) I very much appreciate your help. When I run your code I get errors that they regex is invalid syntax. What I am missing? Is it a Python3 vs Python2 thing?

Comment: @TJB I don't know much Python, but it's running when I test it. What are the errors?