# How to split sentence including punctuation

Tags: string, python-3.x, split, punctuation

If I had the sentence `sentence = 'There is light!'` and I was to split this sentence with `mysentence = sentence.split()`, how would I have the output as `'There, is, light, !'` of `print(mysentence)`? What I specifically wanted to do was split the sentence including all punctuation, or just a list of selected punctuation. I got some code but the program is recognizing the characters in the word, not the word.

```
out = "".join(c for c in punct1 if c not in ('!','.',':'))
out2 = "".join(c for c in punct2 if c not in ('!','.',':'))
out3 = "".join(c for c in punct3 if c not in ('!','.',':'))
```

How would I use this without recognizing each character in a word, but the word itself. Therefore, the output of `"Hello how are you?"` should become `"Hello, how, are, you, ?"` Any way of doing this

Comment: Do you want to obtain a list of non-whitespace chunks of text?

Comment: I specifically wanted to do was split the sentence including all punctuation, or just a list of selected punctuation, therefore if a user wrote a sentence with a comma, the comma would be recognized as a single word.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - Split Strings with Multiple Delimiters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059559/python-split-strings-with-multiple-delimiters)

Comment: I've added some description to my problem

Comment: I don't want to take out the punctuation

Comment: I actually want the punctuation to be recognized apart from the word, so happy! would be happy, !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a `\w+|[^\w\s]+` regex with `re.findall` to get those chunks:

```
\w+|[^\w\s]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cY6mI5/2)

**Pattern details**:

- `\w+`  - 1 or more word chars (letters, digits or underscores)
- `|` - or
- `[^\w\s]`  -  1 char other than word / whitespace

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/sphace):

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'\w+|[^\w\s]')
s = "There is light!"
print(p.findall(s))
```

**NOTE**: If you want to treat an underscore as punctuation, you need to use something like `[a-zA-Z0-9]+|[^A-Za-z0-9\s]` pattern.

**UPDATE (after comments)**

To make sure you match an apostrophe as part of the words, add `(?:'\w+)*` or `(?:'\w+)?` to the `\w+` in the pattern above:

```
import re
p = re.compile(r"\w+(?:'\w+)*|[^\w\s]")
s = "There is light!? I'm a human"
print(p.findall(s))
```

See the [updated demo](https://ideone.com/kxG3Oy)

The `(?:'\w+)*` matches zero or more (`*`, if you use `?`, it will match 1 or 0) occurrences of an apostrophe followed with 1+ word characters.

Comment: Thanks, i'll try that

Comment: What if there are two types of punctuation next to each other, like ('What are you doing?!')

Comment: If you want to get them as separate items, remove the second `+`, I updated the answer.

Comment: One more question

Comment: how do you ignore apostrophe

Comment: Therefore, the sentence 'Happy, it's his name' would output to 'Happy, ,, it's, his, name' ?

Comment: For me, it's recognizing the apostrophe as a punctuation

Comment: Like [`\w+|[^'\w\s]`](https://regex101.com/r/cY6mI5/3)? The `[^...]` is  a negated character class, put the non-word chars you want to exclude there.

Comment: Yeah, i want the program not to recognize the apostrophe as punctuation

Comment: just in the word, not as separate

Comment: like ['Happy, I'm, happy']

Comment: Like p = re.compile("\w+(?:'\w+)*|[^\w\s]")?

Comment: I updated the answer. Let me know if there is anything else unclear.

Comment: Thank you very much