# Split strings based on multiple delimiters while retaining them as well

Tags: python, string, split, whitespace, sentence

I am entering 5 sentences and need them to split using multiple delimiters(,/!/?)

Unfortunately while writing the code I considered only letters and put these delimiters and used .split(). It was working fine then.

this was the code:

```
final_text = ''
split_one = ''
input_text = input("Enter the data: ")
count_d = input_text.count("!") + input_text.count("?") + input_text.count(".")

if count_d == 5:
            final_text = input_text
            final_text = final_text.replace('!', '! ').replace('?', '? ').replace('.', '. ')
            split_one = final_text.split()
            i = 0
            while True:
                print(split_one[i])
                i += 1
                if i == 5:
                    break
```

For an input of : a.b?c!d.f!

```
The output was 
a.
b?
c!
d.
f!
```

But I actually am entering sentences and not letters. E.g

```
hi.how are you? I am good! what about you?bye!
```

It gives me:

```
 hi.
 how
 are
 you?
 I
```

Instead of

```
hi.
how are you?
I am good!
what about you?
bye!
```

What can I do to avoid the split due to white spaces and get it only for the delimiters? (,/./!)

PS: I am not to use any external packages. Version is 3.6

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split Strings with Multiple Delimiters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059559/split-strings-with-multiple-delimiters)

Comment: @AChampion I am not sure I  found a case there when one is entering a sequence of sentences with whitespaces between words and is to split using multiple delimiters while retaining the spaces between words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#module-itertools) to split the string by the punctuation, e.g.:

```
>>> import itertools as it
>>> s = 'hi.how are you? I am good! what about you?bye!'
>>> r = [''.join(v).strip() for k, v in it.groupby(s, lambda c: c in '.!?')]
>>> r
['hi', '.', 'how are you', '?', 'I am good', '!', 'what about you', '?', 'bye', '!']
>>> for sentence, punct in zip(*[iter(r)]*2):
...     print(sentence + punct)
hi.
how are you?
I am good!
what about you?
bye!
```

If you don't care about the punctuation then you can use:

```
>>> [''.join(v).strip() for k, v in it.groupby(s, lambda c: c in '.!?') if not k]
['hi', 'how are you', 'I am good', 'what about you', 'bye']
```

Comment: Kind Sir , thank you for your reply. I am still a beginner in python.Would you mind telling me what should I do with itertools.groupby ?
If its a function , I wont be able to write it as I have just started to learn. 
Is it a built in library package?
Also I am not allowed to external packages.

Comment: It is part of the standard library `import itertools` as a convenience I often give it a shorter name `import itertools as it`.

Comment: Fabulous ! Works like a charm. Thanks a lot for helping me out Sir. Have a good day !