# python split on multiple delimiters bug?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I was looking at the responses to this earlier-asked question:

[Split Strings with Multiple Delimiters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059559/split-strings-with-multiple-delimiters)

For my variant of this problem, I wanted to split on everything that *wasn't* from a specific set of chars. Which led me to a solution I liked, until I found this apparent bug. Is this a bug or some quirk of python I'm unfamiliar with?

```
>>> b = "Which_of'these-markers/does,it:choose to;split!on?"
>>> b1 = re.split("[^a-zA-Z0-9_'-/]+", b)
>>> b1
["Which_of'these-markers/does,it", 'choose', 'to', 'split', 'on', '']
```

I'm not understanding why it *doesn't* split on a comma (','), given that a comma is *not* in my exception list?

Comment: Probably because of `'-/`. It's interpreted as range.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `'-/` inside a character class created a range that includes a comma:

[image]

When you need to put a literal hyphen in a Python `re` pattern, put it:

- at the start: `[-A-Z]` (matches an uppercase ASCII letter and `-`)
- at the end: `[A-Z()-]` (matches an uppercase ASCII letter, `(`, `)` or `-`)
- after a valid range: `[A-Z-+]` (matches an uppercase ASCII letter, `-` or `+`)
- or just escape it.

You cannot put it after a shorthand, right before a standalone symbol (as in `[\w-+]`, it will cause a *bad character range* error). This is valid in .NET and some other regex flavors, but is not valid in Python `re`.

Put the hyphen at the end of it, or escape it.

Use

```
re.split(r"[^a-zA-Z0-9_'/-]+", b)
```

In Python 2.7, you may even contract it to

```
re.split(r"[^\w'/-]+", b)
```

Comment: Didn't know stuff like `\w` works inside `[]`. Thanks!

Comment: ah, thank you! Obvious in retrospect, but wouldn't have thought of it! :)

Comment: I added several things to keep in mind when putting a literal `-` into a character class in a Python `re` pattern. Although this information can be found on SO, it seems scattered in different answers.

Answer (score 2):

The `'-/` is interpreted as range having [ascii](http://ascii.cl/) value from 39 to 47 which includes `,` having ascii value 44.

You will have to put `-`  either at beginning or end or character class.