# Filter out special characters but preserve some

Tags: python, regex

I want to filter out the special characters from a string, but I also want to preserve some of them (for example, I want to preserve apostrophe, &, -, %)

This code will keep the apostrophe, but how can I add the other symbols I want to keep?

```
msg = 'Hi! I'm Mike, I like M&M. How are you?' 

pattern = re.compile("[^\w']")
pattern.sub ('', msg)

>>Output Desired: "Hi I'm Mike I like M&M How are you"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add them like this:

```
import re
msg = "Hi! I'm Mike, I like M&M. How are you?"
pattern = re.compile(r"[^\s\w'&%-]")
print(pattern.sub ('', msg)) # => Hi I'm Mike I like M&M How are you
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/4qz3Lp)

**Details**

- `[^` - start of a *negated* character class matching any char but...

  - `\s` - whitespace
  - `\w` - word char (letter, digit or/and `_`)
  - `'` - a single quote
  - `&` - a `&` symbol
    -`%` - a `%` symbol
  - `-` - a hyphen (since it is at the end, it will be parsed as a literal `-`)
- `]` - end of the character class.

Note you may escape the hyphen to make sure it will be parsed as a literal `-` even if you add more chars after it and forget to escape it: `r"[^\s\w'&%\-]"`.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43352618/python-split-on-multiple-delimiters-bug/43352657#43352657) to learn more how to use a *literal* hyphen inside a Python regex character class.