# Partition a string with more than 1 separator

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I'd like to partition a string with more than one separator, for example:

```
string = 'xxx-yyy/zzz'
```

I'd like my output to be something like this:

```
('xxx', '-', 'yyy', '/', 'zzz')
```

Now, I know the partition method for strings however that only allows one separator, so I can do something like:

```
>>> string.partition('-')
('xxx', '-', 'yyy/zzz')
```

Which isn't what I'm looking for as it doesn't also break up the '/'. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why is this marked as duplicate when clearly `split` is different from partitioning?

Comment: Do you mean that [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1059601/2301450) answer doesn't work for you? Does `re.split('([-/])', string)` not produce the output you need?

Comment: Just tried it now, my apologies.