# Python. How to parse text by section?

Tags: python, parsing, text

So, i have sections and text in these sections:

```
[Section1]
Some weired text in section 1

[Section2]
Some text in section 2
Some text
text
```

And how to get text from one of these sections?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split Strings with Multiple Delimiters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059559/split-strings-with-multiple-delimiters)

Comment: Read about [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/configparser.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import re
sections = re.split(r'\[Section\d+\]', text)
```

Then you can get one of section text using list slicing. In your case:

```
section[1] will give section 1.
```

Comment: One of these. Not all.

Comment: Also consider using [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/configparser.html)

Answer (score 1):

As shown, this code generates a dictionary of the lines in each section, in order, indexed by the section names.

It reads through the file line by line. When it recognises a section header it notes the name. As it reads subsequent lines, until it reads the next header, it saves them in `sections`, as a list under that name.

If you don't want or need the line-ends then strip them off in the `append` statement.

```
>>> import re
>>> patt = re.compile(r'^\s*\[\s*(section\d+)\s*\]\s*$', re.I)
>>> sections = {}
>>> with open('to_chew.txt') as to_chew:
...     while True:
...         line = to_chew.readline()
...         if line:
...             m = patt.match(line)
...             if m:
...                 section_name = m.groups()[0]
...                 sections[section_name] = []
...             else:
...                 sections[section_name].append(line)
...         else:
...             break
...             
>>> sections
{'Section2': ['Some text in section 2\n', 'Some text\n', 'text'], 'Section1': ['Some weired text in section 1\n', '\n']}
```

---

Edit: simplified code.

```
>>> import re
>>> patt = re.compile(r'^\s*\[\s*(section\d+)\s*\]\s*$', re.I)
>>> sections = defaultdict(list)
>>> with open('to_chew.txt') as to_chew:
...     for line in to_chew:
...         m = patt.match(line)
...         if m:
...             section_name = m.groups()[0]
...         else:
...             sections[section_name].append(line)
... 
>>> sections
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'Section1': ['Some weired text in section 1\n', '\n'], 'Section2': ['Some text in section 2\n', 'Some text\n', 'text']})
```

Comment: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'section_name' referenced before assignment

Comment: I suspect that you mistranscribed the code because I just ran it again, with success.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
text="""[Section1]
Some weired text in section 1

[Section2]
Some text in section 2
Some text
text"""
print text.split('\n\n')
>>>['[Section1]\nSome weired text in section 1', '[Section2]\nSome text in section 2\nSome text\ntext']
```