# How to split string by spaces except when enclosed by # # or " "

Tags: python, regex

Hello I have read into using regex but I cannot understand how to use it.

I would like to split a string to make a list, splitting by spaces except when enclosed by # # or quotes " "

```
values = '2 #room 2.# 5 1 -1 -1'
```

or `values = '2 "room 2." 5 1 -1 -1'`

just using split() results in:

```
['2', '#room', '2.#', '5', '1', '-1', '-1']
```

I would like it to output the name of the room without the # and without it split up because of the space:

```
['2', 'room 2.', '5', '1', '-1', '-1']
```

Comment: There is answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059559/split-strings-with-multiple-delimiters

Comment: @Masiama: I don't think that question addresses the issue here. There's no mention of quotes in the first few answers anyway.

Comment: Replace `#` and all non-`"` qualitifiers with `"`, and use [CSV parser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html), see [this demo](https://ideone.com/aC7BYu). If your qualifier chars are consistent across all the input, this should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this (Replace # with " and then use shelex split)

```
import shlex
values = '2 #room 2.# 5 1 -1 -1'
print(shlex.split(values.replace('#','"')))
```

Output

```
['2', 'room 2.', '5', '1', '-1', '-1']
```

Based on awesome observation by  **Casimir et Hippolyte** see the comment

if suppose the values is

```
 values = '2 #"room 2."# 5 1 -1 -1'
```

Then what to do .solution would be make the string simple replace #" and "# to just "

```
import shlex
values = '2 #"room 2."# 5 1 -1 -1'

val=values.replace('#"','"')
print(shlex.split(val.replace('"#','"')))
```

Output

```
['2', 'room 2.', '5', '1', '-1', '-1']
```

Comment: It's a good idea but what if there's a double quote between `#`?

Comment: @Casimir et Hippolyte good observation presently that not the question but if it is like that just will have to replace #" and "# to just "

Comment: something like this import shlex
values = '2 #"room 2."# 5 1 -1 -1'

val=values.replace('#"','"')
print(shlex.split(val.replace('"#','"')))

Answer (score 0):

Instead of describing the delimiter for `re.split`, use `re.findall` and describe the items:

```
re.findall(r'(?<=")[^"]*(?=")|(?<=#)[^#]*(?=#)|[^\s"#]+', values)
```