# How to filter a list using a regular expression?

Tags: python

I have a list of strings with items looking like `"{name, 'test1'}"` or `'{name, "test1"}'` (note the single/double quotes around `test1`).

```
list1 = ["{name, 'test1'}", '{name, "test2"}', "{name, 'test3'}", '{name, "test4"}']
```

How can I filter the list for the "test" strings, that is I want:

```
final_list = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4']
```

Comment: How did you create this list of strings? Clearly something went wrong *earlier* with your data structure. Those strings surely should have been `dict`s, and a single key-pair `dict` is rather pointless anyway...

Comment: try to do regex test[1-9] in your filter

Comment: If those strings are your real data, your problem is completely trivial. If those are not similar to your real data, you are unlikely to receive answers which actually help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059559/split-strings-with-multiple-delimiters and take it from there by finding which ones contain `"test"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you're certain there's an instance of this in every list, I'd use this:

```
list1 = ["{name, 'test1'}", '{name, "test2"}', "{name, 'test3'}", '{name, "test4"}']
final_list = [re.search("[\'\"](.*?)[\'\"]", i).group(1) for i in list1]
print(final_list)
```

of course if you're not certain a 'testx' is available in each string this wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there's a better way to do this instead of regex, but since you asked:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r"""['"](test[^'"]*)['"]""", "".join(list1))
['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4']
```

Comment: What if test is any word, how will you form a regex?

Comment: Frankly, that's a different question, but `r"""['"]([^'"]*)['"]"""`

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of achieving what you want.

NB: I have slightly adjusted the Content of you list to make it a valid list (see other comments).

```
import re


def check_for_match(text):
    return re.findall("test[0-9]", text)[0]

list1 = ["{name, \'test1\'}", "{name, \"test2\"}", "{name, \'test3\'}", "{name, \"test4\"}"]

res = [check_for_match(i) for i in list1]
print(res)
>>>['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4']
```

Comment: Regex not correct, wont match if there another text instead of test

Comment: Correct. My understanding was that just the trailing digit is changing. From the comments I take it I wasn't the only one misunderstanding your question.