# How to extract data from a JavaScript function call like syntax in Python

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm scraping data from a website using scrapy in Python.

Required data lies in a script tag as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
getDetailsfrmBean("storePg","564","Berwyn, IL","7180 W CERMAK RD.","SPACE A1","","BERWYN","IL","US","60402","(708) 788-5097","{Monday-Saturday=10-9,sunday=11-6}","41.8507029","-87.8033709");
</script>
```

I can get this content using xpath as follows:

```
item['lat'] = tree.xpath('//script[@type="text/javascript"]/text()'.extract()[0].encode('utf-8')
item['long'] = tree.xpath('//script[@type="text/javascript"]/text()'.extract()[0].encode('utf-8')
```

Then

```
item['lat'] = 'getDetailsfrmBean("storePg","564","Berwyn, IL","7180 W CERMAK RD.","SPACE A1","","BERWYN","IL","US","60402","(708) 788-5097","{Monday-Saturday=10-9,sunday=11-6}","41.8507029","-87.8033709");'

item['long'] = 'getDetailsfrmBean("storePg","564","Berwyn, IL","7180 W CERMAK RD.","SPACE A1","","BERWYN","IL","US","60402","(708) 788-5097","{Monday-Saturday=10-9,sunday=11-6}","41.8507029","-87.8033709");'
```

But how can I parse these contents so that

```
item['lat'] is equal to "41.8507029"
item['long'] is equal to "-87.8033709"
item['city'] is equal to "BERWYN"
item['state'] is equal to "IL"
```

Can I get any suggestions to solve this.

Comment: You should split the string by comma and then you get an array with values. use the array to get your desired values. keep in mind the value may have a double quote so you may need to remove that too.

Answer (score 2):

Since this call is also valid Python syntax, we can use the `ast` module. Plus the arguments are all string literals, which makes things simpler.

```
import ast

line = 'getDetailsfrmBean("storePg","564","Berwyn, IL","7180 W CERMAK RD.","SPACE A1","","BERWYN","IL","US","60402","(708) 788-5097","{Monday-Saturday=10-9,sunday=11-6}","41.8507029","-87.8033709");'

print([arg.s for arg in ast.parse(line).body[0].value.args])
```

Output:

```
['storePg', '564', 'Berwyn, IL', '7180 W CERMAK RD.', 'SPACE A1', '', 'BERWYN', 'IL', 'US', '60402', '(708) 788-5097', '{Monday-Saturday=10-9,sunday=11-6}', '41.8507029', '-87.8033709']
```

Explanation:

```
print([arg.s           # value of string literal
       for arg in
       ast.parse(line)
      .body            # module (list of statements)
       [0]             # first statement (an Expr node)
      .value           # expression (a Call)
      .args            # arguments to function call
       ])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this with `re`

```
import re
temp_string = 'getDetailsfrmBean("storePg","564","Berwyn, IL","7180 W CERMAK RD.","SPACE A1","","BERWYN","IL","US","60402","(708) 788-5097","{Monday-Saturday=10-9,sunday=11-6}","41.8507029","-87.8033709");'
split_list = filter(None, re.split("[, \-!?:\"]+",temp_string))
print split_list
```

Should produce the following output:

```
['getDetailsfrmBean(', 'storePg', '564', 'Berwyn', 'IL', '7180', 'W', 'CERMAK', 'RD.', 'SPACE', 'A1', 'BERWYN', 'IL', 'US', '60402', '(708)', '788', '5097', '{Monday', 'Saturday=10', '9', 'sunday=11', '6}', '41.8507029', '87.8033709', ');']
```

Picked this up from the answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/23720594/5907969

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple regex to extract just the comma-separated quoted strings part:

```
import re

line = 'getDetailsfrmBean("storePg","564","Berwyn, IL","7180 W CERMAK RD.","SPACE A1","","BERWYN","IL","US","60402","(708) 788-5097","{Monday-Saturday=10-9,sunday=11-6}","41.8507029","-87.8033709");'

args_string = re.match(r'getDetailsfrmBean\((.+)\);$', line.strip()).group(1)
print(args_string)
```

Output:

```
"storePg","564","Berwyn, IL","7180 W CERMAK RD.","SPACE A1","","BERWYN","IL","US","60402","(708) 788-5097","{Monday-Saturday=10-9,sunday=11-6}","41.8507029","-87.8033709"
```

Then there are various ways to parse a list of strings from this kind of data:

```
import ast
import json
import csv

args_array = '[%s]' % args_string

assert (json.loads(args_array)
        == ast.literal_eval(args_array)
        == next(csv.reader([args_string]))
        == ['storePg', '564', 'Berwyn, IL', '7180 W CERMAK RD.', 'SPACE A1', '', 'BERWYN', 'IL', 'US', '60402',
            '(708) 788-5097', '{Monday-Saturday=10-9,sunday=11-6}', '41.8507029', '-87.8033709'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Was about to write an answer which contains both methods with `ast` and `re`+`json` - but @Alex Hall was faster with the `ast` method, which imho is to prefer - but another method would involve a simple regular expression and the json module, which also gives you a list and can scan multiple function calls in the same string:

```
import re
import json

fn_cutter = re.compile("getDetailsfrmBean\((.+?)\);")

for key in item:
  for i, match in enumerate(fn_cutter.findall(item[key])):
    print(key, i, ':', json.loads("[" + match + "]"))
```

[Online demo here](https://repl.it/repls/HandsomeBeigeCgi)

This would save you some time when converting JSON objects to Python structures and catching multiple method calls within the same value - but it will certainly not be able to handle `anotherMethod(args)` or `...value` contained in JS method calls.