# Splitting a string after certain characters?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I will be given a string, and I need to split it every time that it has an "|", "/",  "." or "_"

How can I do this fast? I know how to use the command split, but is there any way to give more than 1 split condition to it? For example, if the input given was

```
Hello test|multiple|36.strings/just36/testing
```

I want the output to give:

```
"['Hello test', 'multiple', '36', 'strings', 'just36', 'testing']"
```

Comment: What is an example string?

Comment: There is `re.split()` using regular expressions

Comment: Use multiple splits, one for each separator.  You'll need to properly `chain` or `map` the extra `split` calls.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split Strings with Multiple Delimiters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059559/split-strings-with-multiple-delimiters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a regex and the regex module:

```
>>> import re
>>> s='You/can_split|multiple'
>>> re.split(r'[/_|.]', s)
['You', 'can', 'split', 'multiple']
```

In this case, `[/_|.]` will split on any of those characters.

Or, you can use a list comprehension to insert a single (perhaps multiple character) delimiter and then split on that:

```
>>> ''.join(['-><-' if c in '/_|.' else c for c in s]).split('-><-')
['You', 'can', 'split', 'multiple']
```

---

With the added example:

```
>>> s2="Hello test|multiple|36.strings/just36/testing"
```

Method 1:

```
>>> re.split(r'[/_|.]', s2)
['Hello test', 'multiple', '36', 'strings', 'just36', 'testing']
```

Method 2:

```
>>> ''.join(['-><-' if c in '/_|.' else c for c in s2]).split('-><-')
['Hello test', 'multiple', '36', 'strings', 'just36', 'testing']
```

Comment: Please add an example.

Comment: Is that the input or desired output? Please add example input and desired output to your question.

Comment: Added an example in the original post

Comment: Thank you! that worked. I was using jupyter notebook and the first command was giving me a weird output.

Answer (score 0):

Use [groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

s = 'You/can_split|multiple'

separators = set('/_|.')
result = [''.join(group) for k, group in groupby(s, key=lambda x: x not in separators) if k]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
['You', 'can', 'split', 'multiple']
```