# How to split several characters in a list in Python 3

Tags: python, list, split, token, reverse

i need to split this list:

```
1 2 3 |4 5 6 |  7  8
```

and make it into this:

```
7 8 4 5 6 1 2 3
```

Till now i only used the split() function, but it only splits the "|" and i get this ['1 2 3 ', '4 5 6 ', '  7  8']. So my question is how to split the blank spaces as well(they could be more than 1).

Comment: But you've also reversed the ordering of the segments in the output? It would be better to do that _first_ before splitting a second time.

Comment: `split` defaults to splitting on blanks; where are you stuck?

Comment: Yes i need to pass through each of the obtained tokens from right to left.

Comment: [Split Strings with Multiple Delimiters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1059559/674039)

Comment: Is the input that you called a list really a string?  Should the output be a list of integers, or a string?

Comment: A reversed list of integers can be interpreted as `8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1` whereas your expected output is different.

Answer (score 2):

You can split the items in the list returned by the first split again in a generator expression:

```
s = '1 2 3 |4 5 6 | 7 8'
print(' '.join(i for t in s.split('|')[::-1] for i in t.split()))
```

This outputs:

```
7 8 4 5 6 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
'1 2 3 |4 5 6 |  7  8'.replace('|', ' ').split()
```

The output will be:

`['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']`

Answer (score 0):

Given what you are attempting to do, splitting on more than just "|" is unnecessary, as the following will work:

```
mystr = "1 2 3|4 5 6| 7 8"
newstr = "".join(mystr.split("|").reverse())
```

To answer how to split on spaces as well

```
mylist = []
for chunk in mystr.split("|"):
    mylist.extend(chunk.split())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
a = "1 2 3 |4 5 6 |  7  8"
print([int(j) for i in a.split("|")[::-1] for j in i.split(" ") if len(j) != 0])
```

this will be output

```
[7, 8, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3]
```