# Split text based on multiple separators ('\n', '/')

Tags: python, nlp, tokenize

Let's suppose that I have a document like that:

```
document = ["This is a document\nwhich has to be splitted\nOK/Right?"]
```

and I would like to split this document (for start) wherever I encounter '\n' or '/'.

So the document above should be transformed to the following one:

```
document = ["This is a document", "which has to be splitted", "OK", "Right?"]
```

How can I do this?

Keep in mind that there may be other special characters etc in the text and I do not want to remove them for now.

Answer (score 2):

Use `re` to split a string of text based on multiple characters or combinations of characters:

```py
document = ["This is a document\nwhich has to be splitted\nOK/Right?"]
re.split("[\n/]",document[0])
```

which produces the requested strings:

`['This is a document', 'which has to be splitted', 'OK', 'Right?']`

Answer (score 0):

This is a unique case where [Regular Expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) shine!
Use Python's `re` module:

```py
>>> import re
>>> document = ["This is a document\nwhich has to be splitted\nOK/Right?"]
>>> re.split(r"[\n/]", document[0])
['This is a document', 'which has to be splitted', 'OK', 'Right?']
```

> [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059559/split-strings-into-words-with-multiple-word-boundary-delimiters) has the most discussion on this topic

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.split()`:

```
import re
def split_document(document):
    if document == []:
        return []
    tmp_str = document[0]
    tmp_list = re.split("\n|/",tmp_str)
    return tmp_list+split_document(document[1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `re.split()` is probably the best solution.

An alternative solution without regular expressions:

```
document = ["This is a document\nwhich has to be splitted\nOK/Right?"]
document[0] = document[0].replace('/', '\n')
document[0].splitlines()
```