# How can I cut my string when scraped 1 tag?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I scraped data from a site with beautifulsoup. The same tag as time and update date. That's why I want to separate them and delete "Update:" string. I couldn't imagine how.

The strings I want should be like this: 
         
         `a="4 July 2019 Friday 07:52"
         b="04.07.2019 07:52"`

```
publishTime=source.find("div", attrs={"class":"textInfo"}).text
print(publishTime.strip())
```

```
4 July 2019 Friday 07:52
                                Update: 04.07.2019 07:52
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split Strings into words with multiple word boundary delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059559/split-strings-into-words-with-multiple-word-boundary-delimiters)

Comment: Can you share the url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this may be what your'e looking for - with no regex:

```
publishTime = '''
4 July 2019 Friday 07:52
                                Update: 04.07.2019 07:52
'''

vars = ['a','b']
vals = publishTime.split(' Update: ')
for var,val in zip(vars,vals):
    sval = val.strip()
    print(f'{var} = "{sval}"')
```

Output:

```
a = "4 July 2019 Friday 07:52"
b = "04.07.2019 07:52"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `Update` expression using regular expressions.

Here is a suggestion on how to to that:

```
import re

str = '''
4 July 2019 Friday 07:52
                                Update: 04.07.2019 07:52
'''

str_changed = re.sub(r'Update:.+', '', str).strip()

print(f'"{str_changed}"')
```

If you run this code, this will print out:

```
"4 July 2019 Friday 07:52"
```