# Split a list based on a lists of unique values

Tags: python

Let's say I have a list called `split_on_these` which I'd like to use split another list, `text` on.  I first pad `split_on_these` so as to not remove naturally occurring instances of `split_on_these` entries:

```
split_on_these = ['iv', 'x', 'v']
text = ["random iv text x hat v", "cat", "dog iv", "random cat x"]
padding = [" " + i + " " for i in split_on_these]
```

I'm trying to create `new_text` that splits on all the items contained in `padding` like so:

```
["random", "text", "hat", "cat", "dog", "random cat"]
```

I tried replacing all the entries of text that are contained in `padding` with some character like `~` and then splitting on that character, but the issue is that when you iterate over the entries in text, sometimes it will be word chunks, and other times it will be individual letters.

Please note that entire chunks preceding a delimiter should be preserved (e.g. random cat).

Comment: Use the ```.split()``` method?

Comment: It's not clear (to me) how to use the split method to split on a list of separators, rather than a single separator.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1059559/4180176

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split Strings into words with multiple word boundary delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059559/split-strings-into-words-with-multiple-word-boundary-delimiters)

Comment: Please clarify: if you have a string "random cat x dog", do you want "random cat" as a single string, or as two separate words?

Comment: @Prune Yes. I just edited the question to make this more clear.  Apologies, I did not consider this problem in advance, but it is an actual issue.

Comment: Okay; in that case, your better solution will lie with regex.

Answer (score 2):

You've already done the "heavy splitting" by padding the divisional words.  What you have left is a split-and-filter sequence

```
text = ["random iv text x hat v", "cat", "dog iv"]
[word for sent in text for word in sent.split() if word not in split_on_these]
```

This splits your padded sentences into individual words and filters out the unwanted words.  Result:

```
['random', 'text', 'hat', 'cat', 'dog']
```

Comment: This won't work for multi-word fragments: processing `['random cat x dog']` will give `['random', 'cat', 'dog']` instead of `['random cat', 'dog']`.

Comment: Ah, good point. Do you have a recommendation for multiword fragments?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Python's `re` [library](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/re.html). It has a more powerful `split` function that lets you split on a regex rather than a single character.

You could create a regex that would match any one of your padding strings, as below:

`re.split("iv|x|v", text)`

The above regex isn't perfect - you'd also have to consider when/whether to match spaces around each padding sequence.