# I have a string containing multiple Date&time values in between along with text. I want to split based on date&time

Tags: javascript, string

Below is the complete string

string = 05-28-2019 23:12:23 - Sora (Additional comments) Is this work really in progress? Please provide a realistic ETA. 05-22-2019 23:56:05 - Sam (Additional comments) Any idea on ETA?

I want to split into two different strings based on date and time

string 1 = 05-28-2019 23:12:23Sora (Additional comments) Is this work really in progress? Please provide a realistic ETA.
string 2 = 05-22-2019 23:56:05 - Sam (Additional comments) Any idea on ETA?

I have used below code

```
<script>
var res = str.split(/^(\s\s\d+)\-(\d+)\-(\d+) (\d+)\:(\d+)\:(\d+\s\s)$/);
</script>
```

Comment: `\s\s\d+` - are there really 2 spaces before the first digit of the date?

Comment: var string = "05-28-2019 23:12:23 - Sora (Additional comments) Is this work really in progress? Please provide a realistic ETA. 05-22-2019 23:56:05 - Sam (Additional comments) Any idea on ETA?";

Comment: Now string 1 should be

Comment: str1= "05-28-2019 23:12:23 - Sora (Additional comments) Is this work really in progress? Please provide a realistic ETA.";

Comment: str2= "05-22-2019 23:56:05 - Sam (Additional comments) Any idea on ETA?";

Comment: why are you repeating the question in comments? I asked if the date is preceded by two spaces

Comment: No spaces in front

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split Strings into words with multiple word boundary delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059559/split-strings-into-words-with-multiple-word-boundary-delimiters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have any specific separator, you do have to use lookaheads in this case.

The code below would be exactly tailored to what you want to achieve.

```
text.split(/(?=\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4} \d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2} -)/)
```