# Splitting a String based on tabs and spaces

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can i split a String with delimeters being \t and ' '(space)?
For example:

```
string="\t Hello   World\t"
newString=['Hello','World']
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split Strings into words with multiple word boundary delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059559/split-strings-into-words-with-multiple-word-boundary-delimiters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `re.split` with the delimiter `[\t ]+`:

```
string = "\t Hello   World\t"
parts = re.split(r'[\t ]+', string.strip())
print(parts)
```

This prints:

```
['Hello', 'World']
```

Note that I strip the leading and trailing whitespace before calling `re.split`.  Also, if you would accept just splitting on any whitespace, we could have used `re.split(r'\s+', string.strip())` instead.