# Python convert string of sql data to list

Tags: python

I have sql data in string form which I'm trying to convert to list.

```
sql = "(10001,'AEX','CCC','X12344','John, Doe','Not indicated','None','No','No','No','\r\n'),(10002,'AEX','CCC','X12344','John, Doe','Not indicated','None','No','No','No','\r\n')"

sql = sql.replace("(", "[")
sql = sql.replace(")", "]")
```

However when I try to convert it to list using list(), it breaks everything.

Comment: Do you want to keep the `'` and `\n\t` in your output?

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1059596/8471995). It lets you split with multiple delimiters

Comment: lots of good answers. However, almost certainly the wrong question. Whatever database driver you are using almost certainly can  format that for you automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `ast.literal_eval` and a nested list comprehension:

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval as leval
>>> sql = "(10001,'AEX','CCC','X12344','John, Doe','Not indicated','None','No','No','No','\r\n'),(10002,'AEX','CCC','X12344','John, Doe','Not indicated','None','No','No','No','\r\n')"
>>> [[leval(x) for x in i.strip('()').replace(",'", "split'").split('split')[:-1]] for i in sql.replace('\r\n', '').replace('),(', ')split(').split('split')]
[[10001, 'AEX', 'CCC', 'X12344', 'John, Doe', 'Not indicated', 'None', 'No', 'No', 'No'], [10002, 'AEX', 'CCC', 'X12344', 'John, Doe', 'Not indicated', 'None', 'No', 'No', 'No']]
>>>
```

Comment: Seems like your solution has one extra empty string (`''`) in each of the lists formed, which should not be in the expected output.

Comment: @Jarvis Edited mine

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution using regex (`re` module in python) :

```
import re
sql = "(10001,'AEX','CCC','X12344','John, Doe','Not indicated','None','No','No','No','\r\n'),(10002,'AEX','CCC','X12344','John, Doe','Not indicated','None','No','No','No','\r\n')"
groups = re.findall('\([^()]*\)', sql)
lists = [list(eval(lst[:-6]+')')) for lst in groups]
```

`'\([^()]*\)'` regex to capture all the characters between all the parentheses (`()`).

`lst[:-6]+')'` to remove the trailing `,'\r\n')` and append `)` (to make a complete 'tuple string') so that `eval` runs smoothly and returns a tuple, then convert it to a list using `list()`.