# Rejoining an array of words such that there are a specific number of lines

Tags: python, arrays, range

I am aiming to do something similar to what might usually be done with something like [`textwrap.wrap`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.TextWrapper.wrap), but instead of wrapping text with a *specified maximum length* I wish to instead specify *how many lines*.

I have split my string into [an array of words at word barriers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059559/split-strings-into-words-with-multiple-word-boundary-delimiters/23720594) and now I want to rejoin my array of strings with a space such that I have a specified number of lines.

Here's what I have so far; `num` is the number of lines I require, `words` is an array of words. `wpc` is an (incorrect) assumption of how many "words per chunk":

```
num = 4
words = [
  "The",
  "quick",
  "brown",
  "fox",
  "jumps",
  "over",
  "the",
  "lazy",
  "dog"
]
wpc = math.ceil(len(words)/num)
chunks = [' '.join(words[num*i:num*(i+1)]) for i in range(wpc)]
```

This gives the incorrect result:

```
[
  "The quick brown fox",
  "jumps over the lazy",
  "dog"
]
```

Which has 3 lines not the 4 required.

Both the list of words and the number of lines required are dynamic, where am I going wrong?

The correct output is a bit dubious.. one possibility is

```
[
  "The quick brown",
  "fox jumps",
  "over the",
  "lazy dog"
]
```

But of course the "3 word" line could be anywhere. It doesn't matter too much how the odd line is placed (first, last, randomly) so long as there are always `num` lines.

Additionally if you added more words it would be good to evenly distribute the words (again, I'm not too fussed how they get distributed):

```
[
  "The quick brown",
  "giant fox jumps",
  "over the very",
  "lazy dog"
]
```

Comment: If there is a 10th word, should the output be of length 3/3/2/2 or 4/2/2/2 (ignoring order)?

Comment: @thesilkworm preferably 3/3/2/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You flipped the use of `wpc` and `num`, and the use of `ceil` is wrong here - I think.

Here's a solution:

```
import math

num = 4
words = [
  "The",
  "quick",
  "brown",
  "fox",
  "jumps",
  "over",
  "the",
  "lazy",
  "dog"
]
wpc = math.floor(len(words)/num)
chunks = [' '.join(words[wpc*i:wpc*(i+1)]) for i in range(num)]

chunks[-1] = " ".join([chunks[-1]] + words[wpc * num:])
```

The result is:

```
['The quick', 'brown fox', 'jumps over', 'the lazy dog']
```

### An evenly distribute solution:

Thqt's slightly more complicated. Basically, I understand what's the minimal number of words per chunk (2 in this case), and randomly spread the extra words between some of the chunks.

```
num = 4
words = [
  "The",
  "quick",
  "brown",
  "fox",
  "jumps",
  "over",
  "the",
  "lazy",
  "dog", 
    "bla"
]

base_words_per_chunk = math.floor(len(words)/num)
extra_words = len(words) - num * base_words_per_chunk
words_per_chunk = [base_words_per_chunk] * num

larger_chunks = random.sample(range(num), extra_words)
for inx in larger_chunks:
    words_per_chunk[inx] = words_per_chunk[inx] + 1

start_point = 0
chunks = []
for inx in itertools.accumulate(words_per_chunk):
    chunk = words[start_point:inx]
    chunks.append(chunk)
    start_point = inx
```

Comment: This is certainly a lot closer than my attempt - but it now just tags extra words onto the last line, instead of redistributing. If you add a couple more words onto the array you'll see what I mean. Thanks again for the answer.

Comment: would you like them to be evenly distributed?

Comment: Yes, that would be awesome!

Comment: Thank you so much!