# str.split with 2 delimiters (or OR other) using python

Tags: python, split

This is my current line:

```
  tableau_indic_final = pd.concat( [tableau_indic['code_Mono'], tableau_indic['Nom_medicament'], tableau_indic['Indications'].str.split(';', expand=True).add_prefix('Indication')], axis=1 )
```

I realized afterwards that I also need to split when there is a ","

So I want the split to happen every time I encounter a ";" OR a ","

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split Strings into words with multiple word boundary delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059559/split-strings-into-words-with-multiple-word-boundary-delimiters)

Comment: What does `expand=True` do in `str.split(';', expand=True)`? I checked [the official python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), and there is no mention of this.

Answer (score 3):

you can use this:

```
import re
new_list = re.split(';|,',your_string)
```

assume that you want to split your string with `:`
then you use:

```
new_list = re.split(';|,|:',your_string)
```

... etc

Comment: Thanks you I'm going to try it like this.

Comment: I tried this but it did not work `tableau_indic_final = pd.concat( [tableau_indic['code_Mono'], tableau_indic['Nom_medicament'], tableau_indic['Indications'].str.split(r';|,', expand=True).add_prefix('Indication')], axis=1 )`

Comment: I also tried `tableau_indic_final = pd.concat( [tableau_indic['code_Mono'], tableau_indic['Nom_medicament'], tableau_indic['Indications'].str.split(r';|,', expand=True).add_prefix('Indication')], axis=1 )` but I get also an error

Comment: @marou95thebest you need to use `re.split` on the string - `tableau_indic_final = pd.concat( [tableau_indic['code_Mono'], tableau_indic['Nom_medicament'], re.split(';|,', tableau_indic['Indications'].str).add_prefix('Indication')], axis=1 )`.

Comment: This time I have `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`

Answer (score 1):

In case you don't want to use regex, you could always replace `;` with `,` and then split on `,` (or the other way around):

```
new_string = your_string.replace(";", ",")
new_list = new_string.split(",")
```

Or, a shorter version:

```
new_list = your_string.replace(";", ",").split(",")
```

In your code, this should work:

```
tableau_indic_final = pd.concat( [tableau_indic['code_Mono'], tableau_indic['Nom_medicament'], tableau_indic['Indications'].str.replace(';', ',').split(',', expand=True).add_prefix('Indication')], axis=1 )
```

Comment: This code retruns me the error: `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'`