# Python function which split string by ',' and ignore ':'

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I need to write a function using regular expressions, `func(string)`, which returns the resulting list as a result of splitting the string. The separators can be enclosed commas with optional spaces or single colons. Look on 'spaces' in example with `:` and `,`. I don't know how to achieve this effect.

Result which I will expect:

```py
>>> func("foo, bar   , sss:s")
['foo', 'bar', 'sss', 's'] 
>>> func("foo"),
['foo']        
>>> func("bla  : bla"),
'bla  ', ' bla'
```

I have this for now:

```py
import re

def func(t):
    match = re.split(r'[,:]', t)
    return match
```

Comment: unclear question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split Strings into words with multiple word boundary delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059559/split-strings-into-words-with-multiple-word-boundary-delimiters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly based on your explanation and the examples provided, there can either be commas with a varying number of spaces before and after the comma itself or colons that do not have any spacing in between. If this is the case, the following should work:

```py
def func(str_to_split):
    return re.split(r':| *, *', str_to_split)
```

The regex `':| *, *'` looks for either a single colon or optional space(s) followed by a comma followed by optional space(s) again.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a good solution:

```
def trim(text):
    return str(text).strip()

result = list(map(trim, match))
```