# How to split a string at multiple points in python

Tags: python, list

In my program, I would like to split the string `"a*h+b=c"` at the signs *, +, =, so the resulting list should look like `['a','h','b','c']`. I have tried using the split command, but it can't split at multiple charactars. Is there a simple command to do this and if not,p plese let me know, or share some ideas. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split Strings into words with multiple word boundary delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059559/split-strings-into-words-with-multiple-word-boundary-delimiters)

Answer (score 1):

A simple regex will work

```
import re
string = "a*h+b=c"
re.split('\W+', string)
```

```
['a', 'h', 'b', 'c']
```

You can also add custom delimiters in [] and the code will look like:

```
import re
s = "a*h+b=c"
re.split('[*+= ]',s)
```

`\w+` matches 1 or more word characters

Comment: You realize that the exact same answer is present in the linked duplicate right?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not like to use re and not familiar with re module and REGEX. Then use my answer

```
string="a*h+b=c"
char_to_split=['*','+','=']
my_list=[]
for ch in string:
    if ch not in char_to_split:
        my_list.append(ch)

print(my_list)
```

prints `['a', 'h', 'b', 'c']`

Hopes helpful!