# How can we write something like Python's `str.split` which accepts an arbitrary regex as input?

Tags: python, string, parsing

Python's `str.split()` method usually accepts a string as input.

For example,

```python
inpoot = "fuzzy#wuzzy#was#a#bear"
outpoot = inpoot.split("#")
print(outpoot)
# ["fuzzy", "wuzzy", "was", "a", "bear"]
```

I want something like `str.split()` except that it will accept an arbitrary regular expression as input.

For something simpler than what I want, we could have a ***predicate***.
The predicate would be a function which:

- accepts single a character as input
- will output a Boolean `True` or `False`

If the predicate outputs `True` when evaluated on input `ch`, then  we consider `ch` to be a delimiter.

- `ch` will be omitted from the output.
- the input string will be split at whatever index `ch` was located at.

```python
def pred_split(stryng:str, is_delim):
    # PRECONDITION:
    #
    #     is_delim.hasattr("__call__") == True
    #
    buffer = list()
    out = list()
    for ch in stryng:
        if pred(ch):
            out.append("".join(buffer))
            buffer = list()
        else:
            buffer.append(ch)
    return out
```

However, the code shown above only works for single-character delimiters.

Suppose that `"::"` is a delimiter, but a single-colon `":"` is not a delimiter. In that case, `inpoot.split("::")` would work. However, my point is that delimiters are often more complicated that single-characters.

We want to split anytime we encounter a string from a set of strings.

```python
import itertools as itts

class MultiSplit:
    itts = itts

    Sentinel = type("Sentinel", tuple(), dict())
    Sentinel = Sentinel() # singleton class  

    @classmethod
    def leaf_iter(cls, lyst)
        raise NotImplementedError()

    @classmethod
    def __call__(cls, stryng:str, delims):
        """
        SOME PRECONDITIONS:
            hasattr(delims, "__iter__")

            for s in iter(delims):
                issubclass(s, str)
        """   
        delims = cls.itts.chain(iter(delim_strs), iter([cls.Sentinel]))
        tree = [stryng]
        for delim in delims:
            if not (delim is cls.Sentinel):
                for idx, leaf in cls.leaf_iter(tree):
                    tree[idx] = tree[idx].split(delim)
        
        return list(cls.leaf_iter(tree))

MultiSplit = MultiSplit()

input = "a::-b-end_c_start-d"
delim_strs = ["::", "end", "start"]

output = MultiSplit(input, delim_strs_
output == ["a", "-b-", "_c_", "-d"]
```

We still don't have quite what we want.
There are several problems, only one of which is that a list of strings is not exactly a regular expression.

Comment: the regex module has a function for this: `re.split`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split Strings into words with multiple word boundary delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059559/split-strings-into-words-with-multiple-word-boundary-delimiters)