# Is there a way to unpack the result of split() inside of for-loop?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, keyword-argument, unpack

I know that maybe the title of the question is not the most intuitive one, but I could not think of better way to describe it in short and here is what I actually mean.

I want to write some small parser, that would build a dictionary of kwargs out of string that I specify.

Here is an example:

```
string_of_kwargs = 'n=6,m=10'
graph_kwargs = {pair.split('=')[0]:pair.split('=')[1]
                    for pair in string_of_kwargs.split(',')}
```

And the output is:

```
{'n': '6', 'm': '10'}
```

The problem is that in the code above I had to use pair.split('=') twice
and I wonder if there is some way to go around it in case I had to unpack more values like this in future.

Comment: You can also [split a string with multiple delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059559/split-strings-into-words-with-multiple-word-boundary-delimiters).

Comment: ```x=re.findall(r"[\w']",string_of_kwargs);graph_kwargs={i:j for i,j in zip(x[::2],x[1::2])}```

Answer (score 8):

Sure:

```py
>>> dict(pair.split('=', 1) for pair in string_of_kwargs.split(','))
{'n': '6', 'm': '10'}
```

Why the `1` as second argument of `split()`? That's in case there are more than one `'='` sign. There is more to do to make this bullet-proof, though, but this is beyond the scope of the question.

Answer (score 4):

You can hackily use a nested for-clause for the binding to a name by iterating over a single-element list like this:

```
graph_kwargs = {
    k:v for pair in string_of_kwargs.split(',')
    for k,v in [pair.split('=')]
}
```

Note, I call it hackey, but it was apparently idiomatic enough to be worthy of a bespoke optimization in [Python 3.9](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.9.html#optimizations), where it basically gets compiled down to a regular assignment instead of actually creating the intermediate list. You can see this for yourself by playing with `dis` different versions of the interpreter.

Comment: Thanks, this trick seems to be more general.

Answer (score 3):

Yet another option (though I would still recommend [using `dict` and a generator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68983773/1126841)):

```
>>> from operator import methodcaller
>>> kv_split = methodcaller('split', '=', 1)
>>> {k: v for k, v in map(kv_split, string_of_kwargs.split(","))}
{'n': '6', 'm': '10'}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know that string_of_kwargs will always be of [same format(trusted input)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice) like ',' separated assignment expression. https://realpython.com/python-eval-function/

```py
# convenient(when dict values itself contain '=' or ',') but risky
# This will evaluate the strings also though, '6' -> 6
eval(f'dict({string_of_kwargs})')
```

```py
from ast import literal_eval
# This will evaluate the strings also though, '6' -> 6
dict((k, literal_eval(v)) for k, v in (pair.split('=') for pair in s.split(',')))
```

Comment: Given that the string is actually called `string_of_kwargs` this might indeed be safe and not as bad as one might think. I don't really see the connection to the second part of the answer, though. (The nested list-comp is exactly how I'd have done it, and evaluating the numeric value might also be a good idea, but it's an entirely different application of eval as in the first part.)

Comment: Yes, you are right. I didn't pay attention to that. Just when I see question, I thought of eval

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regular expression` to split on "," and "=" characters.
Then you can get all the even indexes as keys and odd indexes as values for your dictionary

```py
import re

string_of_kwargs = 'n=6,m=10'
splitted = re.split('=|,', string_of_kwargs) # This will split on = or ,

# Using python list slicing
keys = splitted[0::2] # get all the keys in splitted
values = splitted[1::2] # get all the values in splitted
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regex findall to split the text, and used it to create the dict pair

```
import re
string_of_kwargs = 'n=6,m=10'
x=re.findall(r"[\w']+", string_of_kwargs )
your_dict = dict(zip(x[::2], x[1::2]))
```

Comment: Why not `{k: v for k, v in re.findall("(.+?)=(.+?)", string_of_kwargs)}`?