# How to split on many different delimiters when assigning to dictionary

Tags: python, string, dictionary, split, uppercase

For the sake of practicing how to become more fluent using dictionaries, I trying to write a program that reads the chemical composition of the lunar atmosphere and assign the elements and their estimated composition as a key-value pair like this `"NEON 20":40000`

**The data file looks like this**

```
Estimated Composition (night, particles per cubic cm):
Helium 4 - 40,000 ; Neon 20 - 40,000 ; Hydrogen - 35,000
Argon 40 - 30,000 ; Neon 22 - 5,000 ; Argon 36 - 2,000
Methane - 1000 ; Ammonia - 1000 ; Carbon Dioxide - 1000
```

**And my code so far looks like this:**

```
def read_data(filename):
    dicti = {}

    with open(filename,"r") as infile:
        infile.readline()

        for line in infile:
            words = line.split(";")
            dicti[words[0]] = f"{words[1]}"

    for key in dicti:
        print(key, dicti[key])

read_data("atm_moon.txt")
```

**My question is:**

- How do I split on both `"-"` and `";"`?
- How do I assign the elements and their estimated atmospheric composition as a key-value pair in a simple and elegant way from this data file?
- How do I make the element names all upper case?

Is there anyone who is kind enough to help a rookie out?
All help is welcomed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have here is a list of lines. Each line can contain multiple items, separated by semicolons. Each item (or record) consists of an element name, a hyphen, and the particle count.

You don't need to split on different delimiters at the same time here; instead, you can split out the individual items using the semicolons, and then split each item into the key/value pair you need for your dictionary based on the hyphen.

```
for line in infile:
    for item in line.split(" ; "):
        key, value = item.split(" - ", 1)
        dicti[key.upper()] = value
```

Note that I'm including the spaces around your delimiters, so they are removed when you split. Otherwise those will end up in your dictionary. An alternative would be to use `strip()`; that way it works properly even if there are more (or no) spaces there.

```
for line in infile:
    for item in line.split(";"):
        key, value = item.split("-", 1)
        dicti[key.strip().upper()] = value.strip()
```

However, if there's any chance that one of your records might have a semicolon or a hyphen in it that's *not* meant to be a separator, I'd leave the spaces in the `.split()` call.

Now I'm going to go a step further and assume that you will want those values as actual numbers, not just strings. To do this we'll remove the commas and convert them to integers.

```
for line in infile:
    for item in line.split(";"):
        key, value = item.split("-", 1)
        dicti[key.strip().upper()] = int(value.strip().replace(",", ""))
```

If there were any values with fractional parts (decimal points), you could use `float()` in place of `int()` to convert those to floating-point numbers.

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot! Those look like really good and helpful solutions! However, I get some errors on the last one of your solutions. ```dicti[key.strip().upper()] = int(value.split("-", 1)[-1].strip().replace(",", ""))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '40000 ; Hydrogen - 35000'``` Do you know how to sort this out as well?

Comment: works well without the int(). However, your assumption was right; I would absolutely prefer to have the numbers as ints rather than strings :-)

Comment: I made a stupid assumption which I'm now going to remedy. Stand by. :-)

Comment: Fixed and tested with your actual data. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 2):

I feel like it's easier to use the Python REPL to test this out.

```py
$ python

>>> string = """\
Estimated Composition (night, particles per cubic cm):
Helium 4 - 40,000 ; Neon 20 - 40,000 ; Hydrogen - 35,000
Argon 40 - 30,000 ; Neon 22 - 5,000 ; Argon 36 - 2,000
Methane - 1000 ; Ammonia - 1000 ; Carbon Dioxide - 1000\
"""
>>> lines = string.split('\n')
>>> lines
['Estimated Composition (night, particles per cubic cm):', 'Helium 4 - 40,000 ; Neon 20 - 40,000 ; Hydrogen - 35,000', 'Argon 40 - 30,000 ; Neon 22 - 5,000 ; Argon 36 - 2,000', 'Methane - 1000 ; Ammonia - 1000 ; Carbon Dioxide - 1000']
>>> lines[1:]
['Helium 4 - 40,000 ; Neon 20 - 40,000 ; Hydrogen - 35,000', 'Argon 40 - 30,000 ; Neon 22 - 5,000 ; Argon 36 - 2,000', 'Methane - 1000 ; Ammonia - 1000 ; Carbon Dioxide - 1000']
>>> [line.split(' ; ') for line in lines[1:]]
[['Helium 4 - 40,000', 'Neon 20 - 40,000', 'Hydrogen - 35,000'], ['Argon 40 - 30,000', 'Neon 22 - 5,000', 'Argon 36 - 2,000'], ['Methane - 1000', 'Ammonia - 1000', 'Carbon Dioxide - 1000']]
>>> [line.split(' - ') for line in lines[1:] for line in line.split(' ; ')]
[['Helium 4', '40,000'], ['Neon 20', '40,000'], ['Hydrogen', '35,000'], ['Argon 40', '30,000'], ['Neon 22', '5,000'], ['Argon 36', '2,000'], ['Methane', '1000'], ['Ammonia', '1000'], ['Carbon Dioxide', '1000']]\
```

Finally, creating a dictionary object with the desired mapping:

```py
>>> dict([line.split(' - ') for line in lines[1:] for line in line.split(' ; ')])
{'Helium 4': '40,000', 'Neon 20': '40,000', 'Hydrogen': '35,000', 'Argon 40': '30,000', 'Neon 22': '5,000', 'Argon 36': '2,000', 'Methane': '1000', 'Ammonia': '1000', 'Carbon Dioxide': '1000'}
```

To transform the key-value pairs as desired (i.e. by uppercasing all keys in the dictionary and converting all values to `int`), you can use a helper function to transform the key-value pairs as shown below:

```py
>>> transform = lambda x, y: (x.upper(), int(y.replace(',', '')))
>>> dict([transform(*name_line.split(' - ')) for line in lines[1:] for name_line in line.split(' ; ')])
{'HELIUM 4': 40000, 'NEON 20': 40000, 'HYDROGEN': 35000, 'ARGON 40': 30000, 'NEON 22': 5000, 'ARGON 36': 2000, 'METHANE': 1000, 'AMMONIA': 1000, 'CARBON DIOXIDE': 1000}
```

Answer (score 1):

To split by multiple delimiters, there's regex: [Split Strings into words with multiple word boundary delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059559/split-strings-into-words-with-multiple-word-boundary-delimiters)

Or you can first replace all delimiters to only keep one type, and then use `.split()`

I'm not sure how you want to make a dictionary out of that, but you can always just loop through the newly created list, and assign it one by one (or use a generator). If you include what the dictionary should look like, I can provide an example.

To change string into uppercase, use:

```
"abc".upper()
# ABC
```