# Splitting strings using multiple delimiters- in Python. Getting TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, split

My question is regarding to the data which is being passed in the re.split() function.
I have the following data

| Name | Sport |
| --- | --- |
| John | Football;NBA,Tennis |
| Mary | Squash,Tetris;MMA |
| Scott | Cricket,Tennis |
| Kim | Rugby,WNBA;Footy |

I am trying to split the strings using ';' and ',' as the delimiters. Initially the data type of the Name and Sports column is 'object'

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import re
df = pd.read_excel(r'Filepath\sports.xlsx',sheet_name = 'data')
df[['Name','Sport']] = df[['Name','Sport']].astype('string')
print(df.dtypes)
df[['A']] = re.split(r';,',df['Sport'])
df
```

After converting to string and then trying to split. I get the following error.

```
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

I tried using

```
df[['A']] = re.split(r';,',df['Sport'].astype('string'))
```

But the error is till persisting. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split Strings into words with multiple word boundary delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059559/split-strings-into-words-with-multiple-word-boundary-delimiters)

Comment: Post the full traceback message - we shouldn't have to guess where the error is.

Comment: @tdelaney apologies for that. I can't post the full traceback message as the original data is confidential. I have generated sample data here with the variables changed to reflect that. However, I get your point and therefore I should have posted that I was getting an error for this line of code within the code block. Hope this clears any doubts.
df[['A']] = re.split(r';,',df['Sport'])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

re is a library that recieves a String type, not a Pandas dataframe column you should use an accessor in this case

```
df[['A']] = df['Sport'].str.split(r';,')
```

I hope it resolves your problem