# Multiple input split() method types for the same variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

The following code will get a list as input, and it will use the split method to split the input list with a space.

```
student_heights = input("Input a list of student heights ").split()
for n in range(0, len(student_heights)):
  student_heights[n] = int(student_heights[n])
```

If I wanted to split with comma, I will just ad a comma on the `split()` method above and that would be `split(", ")`

My question is, what if I want it separated both with a space and with , at the same time depending on the user so the user can input the list comma separated or non comma separated. I tried and/or but no luck so far.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split Strings into words with multiple word boundary delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059559/split-strings-into-words-with-multiple-word-boundary-delimiters)

Answer (score 1):

If you expect only integers, you might want to split using a regex for non digits:

```
import re
student_heights = list(map(int, re.split(r'\D+',  input("Input a list of student heights ").strip())))
print(student_heights)
```

*NB. to limit the split to space and comma, use `r'[, ]'` in `re.split`, or `r'[, ]+'` for one or more of those characters, but be aware that any incorrect input will trigger an error during the conversion to int.*

example:

```
Input a list of student heights 1 23,  456
[1, 23, 456]
```

Alternative with `re.findall`:

```
student_heights = list(map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', input("Input a list of student heights ")))
```

and for floats:

```
student_heights = list(map(float, re.findall(r'\d+(?:\.\d*)?', input("Input a list of student heights "))))
```

example:

```
Input a list of student heights 1, 2.3  456.

[1.0, 2.3, 456.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `replace` method as well:

```
student_heights = input("Input a list of student heights ").replace(',',' ').split()

student_heights
>>> out
'''
Input a list of student heights 12,15, 20 25
['12', '15', '20', '25']
```