# How to extract largest possible string's alpha substrings

Tags: python, substring

I want to extract some kind of variable names from the string (digits, _, etc. not allowed), without any imports (pure python only) and as short as possible (even if it's unreadable).

How can i do it?

Example:

"asd123*456qwe_h" -> [asd, qwe, h].

('a', 'qw', etc. not allowed)

Comment: Why no regular expression? This is a great use case for regular expressions.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at e.g. the documentation for the string type, maybe that gives you some inspiration?

Comment: Use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1157498/2055998) as a guideline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Built-ins only:

```
s = 'asd123*456qwe_h'
print(s.translate(str.maketrans({k: ' ' for k in s if not k.isalpha()})).split())
```

**Output:**

```
['asd', 'qwe', 'h']
```

Comment: Shorter: `''.join(c*c.isalpha()or' 'for c in s).split()`

Comment: Very nice and almost as short as Kelly Bundy's mini-skirt! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.groupby` and `str.isalpha` which will test for letters only:

```
["".join(g) for k, g in groupby(s, str.isalpha) if k]
```

Comment: The second code fails even their example.