# What's the fast way to split a unicode string into a list, using white spaces OR punctuation as a separator?

Tags: python, regex

```
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
 import string
 s = u"Dobre uczynki są jak dobre poematy. Można łatwo uchwycić, ku czemu zmierzają, lecz nie zawsze da się je racjonalnie wytłumaczyć."
 exclude = set(string.punctuation)
 s = ''.join(ch for ch in s if ch not in exclude)
 s = s.split()
 print s
```

prints...

```
 [u'Dobre', u'uczynki', u's\u0105', u'jak', u'dobre', u'poematy', u'Mo\u017cna', u'\u0142atwo', u'uchwyci\u0107', u'ku', u'czemu', u'zmierzaj\u0105', u'lecz', u'nie', u'zawsze', u'da', u'si\u0119', u'je', u'racjonalnie', u'wyt\u0142umaczy\u0107']
```

It seems to be not only inelegant, but also slow.

Can you find any better solution? Maybe using regex?

Comment: possible duplicate of [split string on a number of different characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373459/split-string-on-a-number-of-different-characters)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [re.compile](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.compile) if you will have to re-use the regular expression and use [re.split](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.split).

```
import string
import re

s = u"Dobre uczynki są jak dobre poematy. Można łatwo uchwycić, ku czemu zmierzają, lecz nie zawsze da się je racjonalnie wytłumaczyć."
regex = re.compile(r'[%s\s]+' % re.escape(string.punctuation))
print regex.split(s)
```

Comment: Upvoted as my solution, while more compact, does not account for strings with numbers in them.

Comment: @zarkdav: Your solution does correctly split "Mary had 1 lamb", or "I was at EuroScipy2010", so I upvoted your solution. :)

Comment: i tested but i didn't anwer...!

Answer (score 1):

Use [Regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html?highlight=regex#re.RegexObject.split)!

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
s = u"Dobre uczynki są jak dobre poematy. Można łatwo uchwycić, ku czemu zmierzają, lecz nie zawsze da się je racjonalnie wytłumaczyć."
print re.split('\W+', s, flags=re.UNICODE)
```

You could use a more specific regex of course, but this one seems to fit the bill.

Note that the `flags` parameter is for python 2.7+. If you're using an earlier version, simply use `'\W+(?u)'` as your regex.

Comment: Or he/she can just compile the regular expression with re.compile() and let that take the flags argument. Good catch on the '\W+'!

Answer (score 0):

This should do it. (I'll admit that I haven't tested it yet though)

```
import re, string
s = 'your string ...'
re.split('\s'+''.join(string.punctuation), s)
```

EDIT: Don't use mine. Mahmoud Abdelkader's answer above is better.

Answer (score 0):

I would use nltk and here's why:

```
# coding: utf-8
from time import time
import nltk
import string
import re


def bench(n,s):
    start_1 = time()
    regex = regex = re.compile(r'[%s\s]+' % re.escape(string.punctuation))
    for i in xrange(n):
        regex.split(s)
    stop_1 = time()
    start_2 = time()
    for i in xrange(n):
        nltk.wordpunct_tokenize(s)
    stop_2=time()
    print "Regex: {} nltk:{}".format((stop_1-start_1),(stop_2-start_2))


bench(1000000, u"Dobre uczynki są jak dobre poematy. Można łatwo uchwycić, ku czemu zmierzają, lecz nie zawsze da się je racjonalnie wytłumaczyć.")
```

Regex: 22.7673070431 nltk:16.1646370888