# Reading a text until matched string and print it as a single line

Tags: python

I am trying to write a program as a python beginner.
This function scans the given text. Whenever I come across the symbols “@, &, % or $”, I have to take the text until that point and print it as a single line. Also, I have to skip the symbol, start the next line from the letter right after the symbol and print it until I come across another symbol.
I hope I told it well.

```
symbols= "@, &, %, $”"
for symbol in text:
     if text.startswith (symbols):
        print (text)
```

I know it's not correct but that was all I could think. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [split string on a number of different characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373459/split-string-on-a-number-of-different-characters)

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you need to split the string by each of the delimiters, so you could do the following:

```
symbols = "@, &, %, $".split(', ')
print(symbols)  # this is a list

text = "The first @ The second & and here you have % and finally $"

# make a copy of text
replaced = text[:]

# unify delimiters
for symbol in symbols:
    replaced = replaced.replace(symbol, '@')

print(replaced)  # now the string only have @ in the place of other symbols

for chunk in replaced.split('@'):
    if chunk:  # avoid printing empty strings
        print(chunk)
```

**Output**

```
['@', '&', '%', '$']  # print(symbols)
The first @ The second @ and here you have @ and finally @  # print(replaced)
The first 
 The second 
 and here you have 
 and finally
```

The first step:

```
symbols = "@, &, %, $".split(', ')
print(symbols)  # this is a list
```

converts your string to a list. The second step replaces, using [replace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace), all symbols with only one because [str.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) only works with a single string:

```
# unify delimiters
for symbol in symbols:
    replaced = replaced.replace(symbol, '@')
```

The third and final step is to split the string by the chosen symbol (i.e `@`):

```
for chunk in replaced.split('@'):
    if chunk:  # avoid printing empty strings
        print(chunk)
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was trying to do. Have a nice day :)) @DaniMesejo

Answer (score 0):

If I follow the instructions given to you literally, I believe it translates into nothing fancier than just replacing each of those 4 special characters in the text by a newline character:

```
text = """This is a line with @ and & in it.
This line has % and $ in it.
This line has nothing intersting in it.
This line has just @ in it.
The end.
"""
text = text.replace('@', '\n').replace('&', '\n').replace('%', '\n').replace('$', '\n')
print(text)
```

Prints:

```
This is a line with 
 and 
 in it.
This line has 
 and 
 in it.
This line has nothing intersting in it.
This line has just 
 in it.
```